# Using fflush(stdin)

Tags: c, stdin, fflush

So a quick Google search for `fflush(stdin)` for clearing the input buffer reveals numerous websites warning against using it. And yet that's exactly how my CS professor taught the class to do it.

How bad is using `fflush(stdin)`? Should I really abstain from using it, even though my professor is using it and it seems to work flawlessly?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html

Comment: Both [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx)
and [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) define the behaviour of
`fflush()` on an input stream, and even define it the same way (miracle
of miracles). The POSIX, C and C++ standards for
[`fflush()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html)
do not define the behaviour, but none of them prevent a system from
defining it. If you're coding for maximum portability, avoid
`fflush(stdin)`; if you're coding for platforms that define the
behaviour, use it — but be aware that it is not portable.

Comment: Cygwin is an example of a fairly common platform on which `fflush(stdin);` does not clear the input.

Comment: It also depends on exactly what you expect `fflush(stdin)` to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The windows doc says`If the stream was opened in read mode, or if the stream has no buffer, the call to fflush has no effect, and any buffer is retained`, and the linux doc says `For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.` That's not exactly the same way, windows retains the buffer, and linux discards the buffer.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Simple: this is undefined behavior, since `fflush` is meant to be called on an output stream. This is an excerpt from the C standard:

> int fflush(FILE *ostream);
>
> ostream points to an output stream or
> an update stream in which the most
> recent operation was not input, the
> fflush function causes any unwritten
> data for that stream to be delivered
> to the host environment to be written
> to the file; otherwise, the behavior
> is undefined.

So it's not a question of "how bad" this is. `fflush(stdin)` is simply not portable, so you should not use it if you want your code to be portable between compilers.

Comment: In his defense, knowing what is and isn't "undefined behavior" basically means having the whole C specification memorized...  `fflush(stdin)` is actually a very common mistake.

Comment: @BlueRaja: there's defense for a newbie mistake here, but **no defense for a teacher** propagating wrong knowledge! Any reference of `fflush` makes clear it's meant for output streams right in the first paragraph, you don't have to memorize the C standard for that!

Comment: @Eli: No one can know everything.  The processor will never know his mistake until someone tells him...  I used `fflush(stdin)` for years until I discovered it's UB (by accident)

Comment: Err, shouldn't one normally consult the documentation for a function before they use it? Especially a professor?

Comment: @EliBendersky So it's safe to use it with output streams?!

Comment: Another point of defense would be the following part of the man page (various glibc versions on Linux): "For input streams, `fflush()` discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not  been  consumed by the application.  The open status of the stream is unaffected." Although it's UB, some implementations seem to make guarantees without mentioning its status with respect to the standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Under the "CONFORMING TO" section of the glibc man page: "The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams." That's a good section to read sometimes. :) So even glibc mentions that it's not standard behavior, and even that it is undefined. So it shouldn't be used in order to be standard-compliant/portable/what-have-you.

Comment: @VictorZamanian: it depends on what you mean by 'undefined behaviour'. On Linux, the manual defines the behaviour; using `fflush(stdin)` is defined behaviour on Linux.  It is not defined according to the standards (so it does not conform to any standard-mandated behaviour in this instance), but it is defined by Linux (or, more accurately, by glibc).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am of course referring to the standard, not *implementation-defined behavior* as Linux's and glibc's behaviors are.

Comment: There's another aspect that I seldom see mentioned: `fflush(stdin)` is much worse than just implementation-defined behavior. **Even if it did work as most people intend to, it would terrible.** Imagine if stdin is not someone dumbly typing input, but came from another program or shell redirection: it would read the beginning of the file and then just erase the rest. It is really dumb to think that stdin is always something so slow as a human operator.

Comment: @klutt I have updated my answer to be a bit milder, saying that it shouldn't be used for portable code.

Comment: @EliBendersky Removed the downvote. But I still think it's a bit hard. It has the undertone of "real programmers write portable code", but if your code is only intended to be run on Linux, then it's perfectly fine to use all gcc extensions. I mean, why wouldn't you? Just add some checks in the build script and document it. If you want the code to be truly portable, there's A LOT to think of. Just as an example, you don't assume the target computer have a monitor and a keyboard, do you? ;)

Comment: @EliBendersky I think the important thing is to be aware of that you're using extensions. And that you add some guard code, just in case someone is trying to compile it with a different compiler.

Answer (score 53):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

## TL;DR — ***Portable code doesn't use `fflush(stdin)`***

The rest of this answer explains why portable code does not use `fflush(stdin)`.  It is tempting to add "reliable code doesn't use `fflush(stdin)`", which is also generally true.

### Standard C and POSIX leave `fflush(stdin)` as undefined behaviour

The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html), C and C++ standards for `fflush()` explicitly state that the behaviour is undefined (because `stdin` is an input stream), but none of them prevent a system from defining it.

ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — the C11 Standard — says:

> #### [§7.21.5.2 The fflush function](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2)
>
> ¶2 If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

POSIX mostly defers to the C standard but it does mark this text as a C extension.

> [CX] ⌦ For a stream open for reading, if the file is not already at EOF, and the file is one capable of seeking, the file offset of the underlying open file description shall be set to the file position of the stream, and any characters pushed back onto the stream by `ungetc()` or `ungetwc()` that have not subsequently been read from the stream shall be discarded (without further changing the file offset). ⌫

Note that terminals are not capable of seeking; neither are pipes or sockets.

### Microsoft defines the behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` as a no-op

In 2015, [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) and the Visual Studio runtime used to define the behaviour of `fflush()` on an input stream like this (but the link leads to different text in 2021 — and even the text in the  '2015' version is different):

> If the stream is open for input, `fflush` clears the contents of the buffer.

[M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin#comment40866432_2979209):

> Cygwin is an example of a fairly common platform on which `fflush(stdin)` does not clear the input.

This is why this answer version of my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin#comment31066899_2979209) notes 'Microsoft and the Visual Studio runtime' — if you use a non-Microsoft C runtime library, the behaviour you see depends on that library.

[Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) pointed out to me in a comment to another question that, at some time before June 2021, Microsoft changed its description of [`fflush()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=msvc-160) compared with what was originally specified when this answer was written in 2015.  It now says:

> If the stream was opened in read mode, or if the stream has no buffer, the call to `fflush` has no effect, and any buffer is retained. A call to `fflush` negates the effect of any prior call to `ungetc` for the stream.

[*Caveat Lector:*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caveat_lector) it is probably best not to rely on `fflush(stdin)` on any platform.

### Linux documentation and practice seem to contradict each other

Surprisingly, [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) nominally documents the behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` too, and even defines it the same way (miracle of miracles).  This quote is from 2015.

> For input streams, `fflush()` discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.

In 2021, the quote changes to:

> For input streams, `fflush()` discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application. The open status of the stream is unaffected.

And another source for [`fflush(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) on Linux agrees (give or take paragraph breaks):

> For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files, but not pipes or terminals), `fflush()` discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.

Neither of these explicitly addresses the points made by the POSIX specification about `ungetc()`.

In 2021, [zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zwol) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin/34247021?noredirect=1#comment120026978_34247021) that the Linux documentation has been improved.
It seems to me that there is still room for improvement.

In 2015, I was a bit puzzled and surprised at the Linux documentation saying that `fflush(stdin)` will work.
Despite that suggestion, it most usually does not work on Linux.  I just checked the documentation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; it says what is quoted above, but empirically, it does not work — at least when the input stream is a non-seekable device such as a terminal.

#### `demo-fflush.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    if ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Got %c; enter some new data\n", c);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    if ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("Got %c\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ ./demo-fflush
Alliteration
Got A; enter some new data
Got l
$
```

This output was obtained on both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Mac OS X 10.11.2.  To my understanding, it contradicts what the Linux manual says.  If the `fflush(stdin)` operation worked, I would have to type a new line of text to get information for the second `getchar()` to read.

Given what the POSIX standard says, maybe a better demonstration is needed, and the Linux documentation should be clarified.

#### `demo-fflush2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    if ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Got %c\n", c);
        ungetc('B', stdin);
        ungetc('Z', stdin);
        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Huh?!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Got %c after ungetc()\n", c);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    if ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("Got %c\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

Note that `/etc/passwd` is a seekable file.  On Ubuntu, the first line looks like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

On Mac OS X, the first 4 lines look like:

```
##
# User Database
# 
# Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
```

In other words, there is commentary at the top of the Mac OS X `/etc/passwd` file.  The non-comment lines conform to the normal layout, so the `root` entry is:

```
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
$ ./demo-fflush2 < /etc/passwd
Got r
Got Z after ungetc()
Got o
$ ./demo-fflush2
Allotrope
Got A
Got Z after ungetc()
Got B
$
```

Mac OS X 10.11.2:

```
$ ./demo-fflush2 < /etc/passwd
Got #
Got Z after ungetc()
Got B
$
```

The Mac OS X behaviour ignores (or at least seems to ignore) the `fflush(stdin)` (thus not following POSIX on this issue).  The Linux behaviour corresponds to the documented POSIX behaviour, but the POSIX specification is far more careful in what it says — it specifies a file capable of seeking, but terminals, of course, do not support seeking.  It is also much less useful than the Microsoft specification.

### Summary

Microsoft documents the behaviour of `fflush(stdin)`, but that behaviour has changed between 2015 and 2021.  Apparently, it works as documented on the Windows platform, using the native Windows compiler and C runtime support libraries.

Despite documentation to the contrary, it does not work on Linux when the standard input is a terminal, but it seems to follow the POSIX specification which is far more carefully worded.  According to the C standard, the behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` is undefined.  POSIX adds the qualifier 'unless the input file is seekable', which a terminal is not.  The behaviour is not the same as Microsoft's.

Consequently, ***portable code does not use `fflush(stdin)`***.  Code that is tied to Microsoft's platform may use it and it may work as expected, but beware of the portability issues.

#### POSIX way to discard unread terminal input from a file descriptor

The POSIX standard way to discard unread information from a terminal file descriptor (as opposed to a file stream like `stdin`) is illustrated at [How can I flush unread data from a tty input queue on a Unix system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938882/how-can-i-flush-unread-data-from-a-tty-input-queue-on-a-unix-system).  However, that is operating below the standard I/O library level.

Comment: That is probably the better answer in the context of what the OP asked for, although the accepted one is not wrong. To show clearly that it isn´t standard-compliant on one side, but showing that it might be right used on a specific implementation on the other. +1

Comment: The Linux manpage has been corrected since this answer was written.  It now reads "For input streams _associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files, but not pipes or terminals)_, fflush() discards any buffered data ..."  (added text in italics) I can also personally attest that glibc never intended to extend the behavior of fflush beyond what is specified by POSIX.

Comment: @zwol — I've updated the answer once more with revised quotes from the Linux manuals (as found on man7.org and die.net).  Those manual pages are better, but still don't specify what the POSIX standard specifies about discarding characters pushed back by `ungetc()`.  IMO, they still concentrate a bit too much on absolute minimality to the detriment of clarity of intent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You might want to raise the issue with <linux-man@vger.kernel.org>.  They've been very responsive to suggested corrections in my experience.

Answer (score 24):

According to the standard, `fflush` can only be used with output buffers, and obviously `stdin` isn't one. However, [some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) standard C libraries provide the use of `fflush(stdin)` as an extension. In that case you can use it, but it will affect portability, so you will no longer be able to use any standards-compliant standard C library on earth and expect the same results.

Answer (score 16):

I believe that you should never call `fflush(stdin)`, and for the simple reason that you should never even find it necessary to try to flush input in the first place.  Realistically, there is only one reason you might think you had to flush input, and that is: to get past some bad input that `scanf` is stuck on.

For example, you might have a program that is sitting in a loop reading integers using `scanf("%d", &n)`.  Soon enough you'll discover that the first time the user types a non-digit character like `'x'`, [the program goes into an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code).

When faced with this situation, I believe you basically have three choices:

1. Flush the input somehow (if not by using `fflush(stdin)`, then by calling `getchar` in a loop to read characters until `\n`, as is often recommended).
2. Tell the user not to type non-digit characters when digits are expected.
3. [Use something other than `scanf` to read input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf).

Now, if you're a beginner, `scanf` *seems* like the easiest way to read input, and so choice #3 looks scary and difficult.  But #2 seems like a real cop-out, because everyone knows that user-unfriendly computer programs are a problem, so it'd be nice to do better.  So all too many beginning programmers get painted into a corner, feeling that they have no choice but to do #1.  They more or less have to do input using `scanf`, meaning that it will get stuck on bad input, meaning that they have to figure out a way to flush the bad input, meaning that they're sorely tempted to use `fflush(stdin)`.

I would like to encourage all beginning C programmers out there to make a different set of tradeoffs:

1. During the earliest stages of your C programming career, before you're comfortable using anything other than `scanf`, just *don't worry about bad input*.  Really.  Go ahead and use cop-out #2 above.  Think about it like this: You're a beginner, there are lots of things you don't know how to do yet, and one of the things you don't know how to do yet is: deal gracefully with unexpected input.
2. As soon as you can, [learn how to do input using functions other than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf).  At that point, you can start dealing gracefully with bad input, and you'll have many more, much better techniques available to you, that won't require trying to "flush the bad input" at all.

Or, in other words, beginners who are still stuck using `scanf` should feel free to use cop-out #2, and when they're ready they should graduate from there to technique #3, and nobody should be using technique #1 to try to flush input at all -- and certainly not with `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: One point to nitpick because it is a little ambiguous I think and someone might get you wrong: "*Flush the input somehow (if not by using `fflush(stdin)`, then by calling `getchar` to read characters until `\n`, as is often recommended).*" - One call to `getchar()` doesn´t read character**s** until it finds `\n`. If there are several characters, one call to `getchar()` will only fetch the last character entered, not all up to and also not including the newline. Furthermore, `getchar()` also can consume a newline.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Good point, and I don't know why it took so long for me to address it.  Wording adjusted to "calling `getchar` in a loop".

Answer (score 9):

Using `fflush(stdin)` to flush input is kind of like [dowsing for water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowsing) using a stick shaped like the letter "S".

And helping people to flush input in some "better" way is kind of like rushing up to an S-stick dowser and saying "No, no, you're doing it wrong,
you need to use a Y-shaped stick!".

In other words, the real problem isn't that `fflush(stdin)` doesn't work.  Calling `fflush(stdin)` is a symptom of an underlying problem.  Why are you having to "flush" input at all?  *That's* your problem.

And, usually, that underlying problem is that you're using `scanf`, in one of its many unhelpful modes that unexpectedly leaves newlines or other "unwanted" text on the input.  The best long-term solution, therefore, is to [learn how to do input using better techniques than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf), so that you don't have to deal with its unhandled input and other idiosyncrasies at all.

Comment: Though I guess you forgot about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884121/918959

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the pointer, but, no, I didn't forget; both answers are linked in my notes on this topic. There are yet more good, canonical answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219549/ .

Comment: What I mean is they're on the same question :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I get that.  When I posted the second one, SO asked me "You already have an answer to this question, are you sure you want to answer again?", and I answered, "Yes."  For these eternal questions, I'm always trying to find different/better/alternative ways of answering them.  (Another example is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/ .)

Answer (score 5):

None of the existing answers point out a key aspect of the issue.

If you find yourself *wanting* to "clear the input buffer", you're probably writing a command-line interactive program, and it would be more accurate to say that what you want is to *discard characters from the current **line** of input that you haven't already read.*

**This is not what `fflush(stdin)` does.**  The C libraries that support using `fflush` on an input stream, document it as either doing *nothing,* or as discarding *buffered data that has been read from the underlying file but not passed to the application*.  That can easily be either *more* or *less* input than the rest of the current line.  It probably does work by accident in a lot of cases, because the terminal driver (in its default mode) supplies input to a command-line interactive program one line at a time.  However, the moment you try to feed input to your program from an actual file on disk (perhaps for automated testing), the kernel and C library will switch over to buffering data in large "blocks" (often 4 to 8 kB) with no relationship to line boundaries, and you'll be wondering why your program is processing the first line of the file and then skipping several dozen lines and picking up in the *middle* of some apparently random line below.  Or, if you decide to test your program on a very *long* line typed by hand, then the terminal driver won't be able to give the program the whole line at once and `fflush(stdin)` won't skip all of it.

So what should you do instead?  The approach that I prefer is, if you're processing input one line at a time, then *read an entire line all at once*.  The C library has functions specifically for this: `fgets` (in C90, so fully portable, but does still make you process very long lines in chunks) and `getline` (POSIX-specific, but will manage a `malloc`ed buffer for you so you can process long lines all at once no matter how long they get).  There's usually a direct translation from code that processes "the current line" directly from stdin to code that processes a string containing "the current line".

Comment: but as `Eli Bendersky` Mentioned fflush is meant to be used on output stream. so if we use on `stdin` causes `UB` .

Comment: @AbhishekMane C implementations are allowed to define behavior left undefined by the standard, and C programs are free to rely on such definitions; it just makes them less than perfectly portable. The point of this answer is that _even if you are OK with relying on implementation extensions_, using `fflush(stdin)` is still a mistake, because the common implementation extensions for `fflush(stdin)` don't do what you actually want.

Comment: Now got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [POSIX](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/3P/fflush/):

> For  a  stream  open  for  reading, if the file is not already at EOF, and the file is one
> capable of seeking, the file offset of the underlying open file description shall  be  set
> to  the   file  position  of  the stream, and any characters pushed back onto the stream by
> ungetc() or ungetwc() that have not subsequently been read from the stream shall  be  dis-
> carded (without further changing the file offset).

Note that terminal is not capable of seeking.