# How to use sscanf in loops?

Tags: c, string, scanf

Is there a good way to loop over a string with `sscanf`?

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
char line[] = "100 185 400 11 1000";
```

and I'd like to print the sum.  What I'd really like to write is this:

```
int n, sum = 0;
while (1 == sscanf(line, " %d", &n)) {
  sum += n;
  line += <number of bytes consumed by sscanf>
}
```

but there's no clean way to get that information out of `sscanf`.  If it returned the number of bytes consumed, that'd be useful.  In cases like this, one can just use `strtok`, but it'd be nice to be able to write something similar to what you can do from `stdin`:

```
int n, sum = 0;
while (1 == scanf(" %d", &n)) {
  sum += n;
  // stdin is transparently advanced by scanf call
}
```

Is there a simple solution I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Look up the `%n` conversion specifier for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) and family.  It gives you the information you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[] = "100 185 400 11 1000";
    char *data = line;
    int offset;
    int n;
    int sum = 0;

    while (sscanf(data, " %d%n", &n, &offset) == 1)
    {
        sum += n;
        data += offset;
        printf("read: %5d; sum = %5d; offset = %5d\n", n, sum, offset);
    }

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Changed 'line' to 'data' because you can't increment the name of an array.

Comment: @Green Code: I've read, and reread, and re-reread, the manual pages for the function over the years, on many machines, and using my copy of the C standard, etc. I think it is actually the first time I've used the `%n` notation, but it works fine. **Beware**: `%n` also exists in `printf()` and has the analogous meaning. It becomes a risk factor because it is an *output* value in a function that predominantly reads values. It is also banned by the secure versions of `printf()` for TR24731. And `%n` can be used with devastating effect by people who manage format string attacks on programs.

Comment: I'm actually aware of %n, yeah, but am wary of using it for security reasons.  But if it's the only way...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is the leading space in the format string of `sscanf` needed because `%d` anyway reads and discards any number of whitespace characters?

Comment: Also could you please explain what is `TR24731` that you mentioned for `printf`?

Comment: @ajay: no, the leading space is not required; I copied it from the question without thinking. [TR 24731-1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#24731-1) "Extensions to the C Library Part 1: Bounds Checking Interfaces" is a Technical Report from the ISO JTC1/SC22/WG14 Committee (aka 'Standard C' committee) that defines 'safer' versions of a number of functions. They are implemented, more or less, by Microsoft (see [Do you use TR 24731 safe functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/372980/)). TR24731-1 is (optional) Annex K in ISO/IEC 9899:2011, the current version of the C standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much :) Every day I feel how little I know and excited at the same time to realize how much there is to learn.

Comment: Am using this to get average of numbers from command line argument , thanks a lot