# Scan a random number of floats until new line in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read from a file with this text inside:

> f 502  601  596  465  464
>   f 597  599  600  598
>   f 602  591  596  601
>   f 588  565  548  260  62  61  595
>   f 583  595  61  558  561
>   f 237  241  471

On each line, there is an f followed by a random amount of floats. I want to be able to take the numbers after the f and store them in an array of structs of floats. I wrote code that will parse the text file if there is three floats on each line but now I am instructed to do it if there is a random amount of floats (up to 13 floats).  Basically the code I have now for three floats on every line is as follows:

```
struct faces {
  float p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12;
}

struct faces eFace[100];

FILE *fp;
char buff[128];
int fCount = 0;
fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
    printf("Can't open file");
else {
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL) {
        if (buff[0] == 'f') {
            sscanf(buff, "f %f %f %f", &eFace[fCount].p1, &eFace[fCount].p2, &eFace[fCount].p3);
            fCount++;
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

}

What would be the best way to modify my code so that it takes every float (up to 13 floats) after "f" until a new line and stores them in the array of the structs I made? I appreciate any help and if you need more information just let me know!

*Note: I always have to check if the line starts with an f.*

Comment: In C++, you'd probably want to read a line into a string, create a `stringstream` of the line, then read a char followed by a `std::vector` of floats from the stringstream (and ignore the char).

Comment: oops sorry, this is for C only. I removed just removed the tag for C++

Comment: In while loop sscanf(" %f",...) and check what sscanf returns if - 0 then you know that your read wasn't succesful, so you;re probably at the next line;)

Comment: Using a structure instead of an array to hold the up-to-13 values is a disaster...you need a loop, and a loop needs an array.  Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with the structure holding an array of 13 floats?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use sscanf in loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)

Comment: You current code doesn't check that the line starts with an `f`; it simply assumes that it does and that there will be three floating point values after it.  You have to check the return value from `sscanf()` to ensure that the correct number of conversions takes place.

Comment: I probably would be better off, I just pasted my old code to show what I have to work with. It does check if it starts with an f. It takes the line from text.txt and put it in buff. it then checks if buff[0] is == to f and if it is then it stores the floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an upper bound to the number of floats, use that, but do not hard-code the 13.

Scan the file twice to determine the number of lines.

Use `fgets()` to read each line.

Use `sscanf()` or `strtod()` to read each number.  Be sure to perform error checking.

Untested code follows:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#define faces_N 13

typedef struct faces {
  float p[faces_N];
} faces_T;

void foo(void) {
  faces_T *eFace = NULL;
  size_t Lines = 0;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    printf("Can't open file");
  else {
    char buff[2*(faces_N*(FLT_DIG + 10) + 1 + 1)];
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
      Lines++;
    rewind(fp);
    eFace = malloc(Lines * sizeof(*eFace));
    assert(eFace);

    for (size_t l = 0; l < Lines; l++) {
      if (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
        Handle_IOError();
      if (buff[0] != 'f')
        Handle_FormatError();
      size_t f;
      char *p = &buff[1];

      for (f = 0; f < faces_N; f++) {
        int n;
        if (sscanf(p, "%f%n", &eFace[l].p[f], &n) != 1)
          break;
        p += n;
      }
      // TBD what to do with other
      for (; f < faces_N; f++) {
        eFace[l].p[f] = 0.0;  // Or maybe NaN or save count in eFace
      }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // do whatever with eFaces;

  }
  free(eFaces);
}
```

The size of `buff` is debatable.  I like 2x the maximum expected size and would throw an error if the buffer was full.

The number of `char` to expect for a `float` should be able to distinguish all `float`.  Estimating via `" -D.DDDDDDddde-dd"`, came up `1 (space) + 1 (sign) + 1 (.) + FLT_DIG + 3 (see link) + 4 (exponent)`.  See the link for a discussion about printing precision:  [width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specificer-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value/19897395#19897395)

Comment: Consider up voting all answers that you felt helped you well (on this and your other questions).  After some time (hours, days - your call) on your various questions, consider "accepting" an answer by clicking the check mark should it well solve your post.  (I see you have accepted 0 for 4)