# usage of scanf inside while test condition

Tags: c, scanf, function-calls

I want to store a series of integers till i press an enter in an array.How can i implement that

Input:
1(tab space)2(tab space)3(tab space)4(tab space)enter

i tried doing this

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j,c,d;
int a[5];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        j=0;
    while((d=scanf("%d",&c))==1){
         a[j]=c;
         j=j+1;
    }
 }
}
```

I dont know how scanf works and using scanf return value.Please explain how i can store this input if its not impossible to do so with scanf and also

2)What else can be used inside scanf along with %d ?

I have a file with 200 rows with numbers like this 
(NOTE: each row has varied number of values but all numbers are less than 200)

```
1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t
2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t
11\t12\t13\t
.
.
200
```

...                 so i have to store this as an adjacency list representation

Comment: 1 question at a time please

Comment: `scanf("%d",...` consumes white-space and does not distinguish between `' ', '\t', '\n'`.  To know when a line ends (finding `'\n'`) codes needs another approach.

Comment: Follow the link for the POSIX view on what you can use with [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).  Be aware that using `scanf()` accurately is surprisingly hard, at least once you get beyond reading integers.  In your code, the assignment to `d` is unnecessary; the variable is never referenced.  It would make sense if there was error recovery code that needed to know how many of the values were read successfully (because `scanf()` can read multiple values with a single call). Consider using `" %c"` instead of `"%c"` when reading characters.

Comment: @chux What would be that approach? and also in the above comment you were saying scanf("%d",..)consumes white-space how is scanf(" %d") different?

Comment: @sarat: note that `scanf()` doesn't pay attention to newlines for most practical purposes.  With terminal input, the program will see nothing until you hit return, but `scanf()` will merrily read past newlines looking for more input.  If you want to do line-based input, use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), and then [`sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops/3975254#3975254.)

Comment: @sarat `scanf("%d",..` and `scanf(" %d",...` are effectively the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question. scanf() returns number of elements successfully read but it is of no use here and you can just scan in a loop and scanf() will pick your integers in a line when you press enter.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[5];
    int i, n;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       if(scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1)
       {
          printf("Value not read correctly\n");
          break;
       }
    }
    n = i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

For the second question you have to do something line

1.Read a line from your file using `fgets()`

2.Break your line using `strtok()` with tab as delimiter.

3.Now convert each token to integer using `atoi()`

4.Now do whatever you want with the integer. i.e. create a node add your integer to the node

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some reasonable assumptions about the width of each row.
These assumptions are useful for simple code, though not needed in general.

```
#define LINE_WIDTH_MAX 1000
#define INTS_PER_LINE_MAX 100
#define ROWS_PER_FILE (200 /* given by OP */)
```

Read each row with `fgets()`, then scan.  Could use `strtol()`, `sscanf()` or various approaches.

This method uses `sscanf()` and `"%n"` to determine when the next number might follow.

```
int row;
for (row = 0; row < ROWS_PER_FILE; row++) {
  char buf[LINE_WIDTH_MAX + 2];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    break;  // Handle EOF or IO error
  }
  int num[INTS_PER_LINE_MAX];
  char *p = buf;
  for (int i = 0; i<INTS_PER_LINE_MAX; i++) {
    int n = 0;
    if (1 != sscanf(p, "%d %n", &num[i], &n)) {
      break;
    }
    p += n;
  }
  if (*p) Handle_GarbageInLIne();

  // do something with the `i` numbers

}
```

Notes:

Advise never use `scanf()`/