# scanf cannot detect EOF but getchar is able to detect EOF input?

Tags: c, scanf, eof, getchar

I was just wondering why my code does not register my <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>Z</kbd> input? When i input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>Z</kbd> it does not exit the while loop somehow.

However when I substitute the `scanf()` function with a `getchar()` function, it suddenly works! could anyone out there help enlighten me on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char grade;
    while( grade != EOF){
        scanf("%c" , &grade);
        switch(grade){
        case 'a':
            printf("you got an a!\n");
            break;
        case 'b':
            printf("you got a b!\n");
            break;
        case'\n':
            break;
        default:
            printf("error :(\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220158/exiting-a-while-loop-at-eof-using-scanf-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While scanf EOF loop misbehaving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713972/while-scanf-eof-loop-misbehaving)

Comment: it's worth noting that Ctrl-Z is the EOF character *on Windows*.  UNIX / Linux / POSIX systems all use Ctrl-D for this (AFAIK).

Comment: Note that  `grade` is not initialized when `while( grade != EOF){` first executes.

Comment: to start 1) the value EOF is a signed integer, not a character.  2) ALWAYS check the returned value, not the parameter value when calling `scanf()`  because the EOF value will NOT be placed in the parameter. 3) the variable `grade` is not initialized before being checked.  4) strongly suggest the `while()` statement be written as: `while( EOF != scanf( "%c", &grade ) )`  Suggest always reading/understanding the man page for any system functions called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `scanf()` function to get the *expected* `EOF`. Checking the argument for `EOF` after the scanning failed is wrong, and may invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), in case the argument is of type automatic local and not initialized.

Quoting from the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) (*emphasis mine*)

> The value `EOF` **is returned** if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and `errno` is set indicate the error.

That said, a `char` is not enough to hold a value of `EOF`, if you have to store the return value of `scanf()` call, use an `int`.

Comment: oh do you mean I should simply change the grade to an integer variable? Ive tried that but it still doesnt work tho...

Comment: @JavierLam nope, check the **return** value of `scanf()` function call.

Comment: Sorry I know it a really noob question, but how do I check the return value of the scanf() function call?:) If its too cumbersome to explain I will understand! I have to sa my basics of programming is rather shaky as I am still new