# after getting an input from user in an array of maximum size 100, how to check how many values user has inputed?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have a restriction on the maximum size of an array (N), and I want to ask the user to input an array of numbers that can be less than or equal to N. How do I find how many values the user has inputted?

This is what I have, and it's not working.

(basically, i'm telling the program to stop counting "n" once the user hits enter) (and ofcourse i initialized n=0)

```
for(i=0;i<(N-1);i++)
{

    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    n++;

    if(a[i]=='/n'){break;}
}
```

any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: The value of `i` after the loop will hold `the number of values inputed - 1` so what you need is the value of `i+1`, once the loop is finished

Comment: Also, saying *it's not working* doesn't mean much. What **exactly** isn't working? What is happening versus what you want to happen?

Comment: first off, sorry i made a mistake, i wrote 0 instead of '/n'.. The code itself is working, but when i input, lets say, 5 numbers, the program is still waiting for me to enter more and doesn't end the program. I want it to stop the program no matter how many numbers i input (as long as its less than N)

Comment: Ok so how will the computer know **when** to stop? You have to tell it somehow. If you want the computer to stop `no matter how many numbers` you input, it still needs some sort of a stoping signal. And i can see that you are telling the computer to stop (break out of the loop) when you enter a newline character or (N-1) is reached. So I still don't see what exactly is your issue. Another thing, if you want your loop to run up to a value *less than or equal to N*, change your loop condition from `i < (N-1)` to `i < N`

Comment: You're reading an integer and then checking to see whether the user entered "10" (ASCII value for newline) rather than whether they actually pressed enter... or would be if you'd used `'\n'` instead of `'/n'`.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: @Dana can you use `fgetc()` and `ungetc()`?

Comment: If I understand your question you want to fill your array with the integers which are entered in a line i.e until a newline char is enountered is it so?

Comment: Note that `'/n'` is a multicharacter constant, not a newline, and it has an implementation-defined value. Generally, `'\n'` (newline) is just a way of writing 10; your code is testing whether the user entered 10, which is a curious 'end of list' value. You should be checking the return value from `scanf()`. If you care about line boundaries, you can't use `scanf()` to read numbers, because `scanf()` doesn't care about line boundaries. If you need to read and parse lines, use `fgets()` (or `getline()`) to read the line and [`sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3975236/) to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because `scanf` with the `"%d"` specifier, will skip the `\n`, you can consume all white space characters and search for `'\n'` with `fgetc()`, the last white space character which is not `'\n'` could be returned to the stream using `ungetc()` so this program probably will do what you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int i;
    int result;

    result = 1;
    i      = 0;
    while ((i < 100) && (result == 1))
    {
        int chr;

        /* 
         * consume all whitespace characters left by previous scanf, 
         * stop if one of them is '\n' 
         */
        while (isspace((chr = fgetc(stdin))) && (chr != '\n'));
        /* found the '\n', set the flag to exit the loop */
        if (chr == '\n')
            result = -1;
        else
        {
            /* not interesting put back this character for scanf to read it */
            ungetc(chr, stdin);
            /* save the result of scanf, that way you can validate input */
            result = scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            if (result == 1)
                i++;
        }
    }
    printf("read %d numbers\n", i);

    /* print the carachters, this will print in reverse obviously */
    while (--i >= 0)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux thanks, done. I am still trying to learn how `scanf` works, not really my favorite function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 100

int main(void){
    int v, a[N];
    int i, n=0, stop = 0;
    int ch, res;

    while(!stop && EOF != (res = scanf("%d", &v))){
        if(res == 1){
            a[n++] = v;
            if(n == N)
                break;
            while(isspace(ch = getchar())){
                if(ch == '\n'){
                    stop = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            ungetc(ch, stdin);
        } else {
            printf("invalid input!\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n');
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Corner case: Fails when 0 numbers are on the line.

Comment: Element is not displayed in the case of zero. Newline is output.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &v)` consumes the `'\n'` and then the while loop will not stop until the _next_ `'\n'`.

Comment: But I think it is whether such things desired by the OP is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

You could ask the user to enter the number of items that he's willing to enter. Let's say that the max number is `N` and that the number of items the user wants is `n`.

```
puts("ENTER NUMBER OF ITEMS");
scanf("%d", &n);

n = min(n, N);
n = max(n, 0);

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

If the user keeps typing numbers and then hits enter to stop, you can read the input line by line and check that the user has typed something or break out of the loop elsewise.

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < N; i++)
{   char s[100];
    gets(s);

    if(strcmp(s, "") == 0) break;
    a[i] = atoi(s);
}
```

The number of items read is equal to `i`. This is less safe and you've got to do some error checking if you are willing to use this solution.

Comment: yes, i know we can do that, but sadly the assignment doesnt allow it :(

Comment: whoever downvoted, write a comment explaining why..