# How to read multiple words in a line in C?

Tags: c

I want the user to be able to type

```
start < read_from_old_file.c > write_to_new_file.c 
//or whatever type of file
```

So once the user types the command "start" followed by a "<", this will indicate reading a file, whereas ">" will indicate writing to a new file.

Problem is, I know you can use

```
scanf("%s", buff);
```

But this would read one word and not go onto the next.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read the whole line, and `strtok()` to find the words.

Comment: Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines.  See also [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",buff);
```

If you wish to use `scanf()` for this.

`%*c` is to get rid of the newline due to hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using the `scanf` family of functions is a bad idea. Instead, you should use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) or [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) to read in data, then perform your own processing on it. `fgets` will read a line at a time, whereas `fread` is for when you don't care about lines and just want *n* bytes of data (good for, say, implementing `cat`).

Most programs will want to read a line at a time. You'll need to allocate your own buddy to pass to `fgets`.