# Ignoring # comments in the input for a C program

Tags: c, comments

I'm trying to write a program which will read from text files and then output the minimum, maximum and average values.  The trouble I am having is ignoring comments in the text files that begin with a hashtag. Here is my working code so far. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
  char ch, filename[20];
  FILE *lun;
  int num, min, max, sum, count, first;

  printf("Please enter the  name of file to load:");
  scanf ("%s", filename);
  lun=fopen(filename, "r");
  if ( lun != NULL)
    {
      for ( sum= count= first= 0; fscanf( lun, "%d", &num ) == 1; sum += num, ++count )
        if ( !first ) { min= max= num; first= 1; }
        else if ( num > max ) max= num;
        else if ( num < min ) min= num;
      fclose( lun );

      printf( " Minimum value: %d\n Maximum value: %d\n Average value: %lf\n",
              min, max, sum / (double) count );
    }
  else
    printf( "Unable to read file.\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not destroy your question, or remove the code from the question, after you have received help on it.  That is not fair to those who have spent time helping you.

Answer (score 2):

Read the data in lines (use `fgets()`).
If the line contains a `#`, terminate the string there by replacing the `'#'` with `'\0'`.  Then scan the line for numbers.
See also [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236)

And don't forget to check that the file was opened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char filename[20];

    printf("Please enter the name of file to load: ");
    if (scanf("%19s", filename) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read file name\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *lun = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (lun == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    char line[4096];
    int min = 0;  // Avoid compilation warnings (may be used uninitialized)
    int max = 0;  // Ditto
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), lun) != NULL)
    {
        char *hash = strchr(line, '#');
        if (hash != NULL)
            *hash = '\0';
        int pos;
        int num;
        int off = 0;
        while (sscanf(line + off, "%d%n", &num, &pos) == 1)
        {
            if (count == 0)
                min = max = num;
            if (num > max)
                max = num;
            if (num < min)
                min = num;
            sum += num;
            count++;
            off += pos;  // Skip through line
        }
    }
    fclose(lun);

    printf("Minimum value: %d\nMaximum value: %d\nAverage value: %lf\n",
              min, max, sum / (double)count);
    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support C99 or later, you will have to move variable declarations to the start of a block (immediately after a `{`).

---

Handling doubles isn't really any harder:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char filename[20];

    printf("Please enter the name of file to load: ");
    if (scanf("%19s", filename) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read file name\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *lun = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (lun == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    char line[4096];
    double min = 0.0;   // Avoids 'used when uninitialized' warnings
    double max = 0.0;   // Avoids 'used when uninitialized' warnings
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), lun) != NULL)
    {
        char *hash = strchr(line, '#');
        if (hash != NULL)
            *hash = '\0';
        int pos;
        double num;
        int off = 0;
        while (sscanf(line + off, "%lf%n", &num, &pos) == 1)
        {
            if (count == 0)
                min = max = num;
            if (num > max)
                max = num;
            if (num < min)
                min = num;
            sum += num;
            count++;
            off += pos;  // Skip through line
        }
    }
    fclose(lun);

    printf("Minimum value: %f\nMaximum value: %f\nAverage value: %f\n",
              min, max, sum / count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'after a decimal'?  After a decimal point?  No; that wasn't part of the specification — you're reading integers, and integers don't contain decimal points (or, at least, they don't in C).  If you want to handle that, you either read into `double` variables, and adjust other types accordingly, or you can detect a decimal point via `if (line[off + pos] == '.')` and then skip over digits until you come across a blank, or thereabouts.  Up to you.  But don't try changing the problem specification part way through — that is unfair to people trying to help you.

Comment: OK; if you need to read number that contain a decimal point, then you need to change the types of `min`, `max`, `sum`, `num` to `double`, change the scanning format from `%d` to `%lf`, and you can use `%f` or `%lf` in the printing formats (instead of `%d` again).  You don't need the cast in the printing line, either, since `sum` is already a `double`.

Comment: (These comments were responses to question comments from the OP.  The question was deleted once, then reinstated when some more information was needed — hence the second comment.  Then the OP found that questions cannot be deleted after there's an answer with an up-vote.)