# Read in digits until a newline character is hit

Tags: c, io, scanf

I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
12345678909876543211234567890
09876543122345678900
```

I will eventually need to add these two values together using separate stacks so I want to push each digit into a stack separately so I have code like the following:

```
test=fopen("test.txt","r");
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf(test, "%1d", &number);
    Push((Item)number, &num1);
}
```

I need to modify my code though so that it reads the first line 1 digit at a time, pushing on each digit, and then for the next line I need it to push into another stack called `num2` instead of `num1` as you see in the current code.

Comment: @user3121023 wouldn't that scan them in as a char though?

Comment: Read a line of data; push the digits onto the stack.  Read the next line; push the digits onto the other stack.  Use the Standard C function [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or the POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the lines.

Comment: See also [Why is `while (!feof(file))` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @user3121023 your method worked properly and I now have it working using that. Feel free to submit an answer and I can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not told us about the stack types, so I'm inventing one — typedef name is `Stack`:

```
Stack num1, num2;
Stack *stacks[2] = { &num1, &num2 };

…initialize stacks
…open file and check that the open was successful

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    char line[4096];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), test) == 0)
        …report unexpected EOF or other error; do not continue…
    char *digit = line;
    while (isdigit((unsigned char)*digit))
        Push((Item)(*digit++ - '0'), stacks[i]);
    if (*digit != '\n' && *digit != '\0')
        …report unexpected (non-digit) data on input; do not continue;
}
```

I assume that `Push` is a function, not a macro that might evaluate its first argument more than once.  If it is such a macro, the loop body needs be split onto two lines and braces added so that the increment of `digit` is separate from the function call.

Note that one major advantage of this method is that you have the whole line of data available for error reporting, which is typically easier for people to understand than only being able to report on the dribs and drabs left over after a semi-indeterminate number of characters was read from the line by a `scanf()` loop.  You can even use `sscanf()` on the line if you want to — see [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)