# Using sscanf() function to read a string

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a begginer so I'm stuck in this part. I need to type a message, and a shift amount by which letters should be shifted to 'encrypt' a message.
The problem is that It's not displaying any text, it just never exits the while loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

   char ch,message[50]={0};
   int shift;


   printf("Enter message to be encrypted: ");
   scanf("%s",message);
   printf("Enter shift amount (1-25): ");
   scanf("%d",&shift);

   printf("Encrypted message: ");

   while((sscanf(message," %c",&ch) == 1) && (ch != '\n'));
   {
       ch += shift;
       putchar(ch);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter message to be encrypted: abcABC
Enter shift amount (1-25): 3
Encrypted message:
```

(Program is stucked there in an infite loop)

Comment: You have ";" in the end of the while statement

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/
you are always reading only the first character form the `message`

Comment: But since your message has a defined size I would suggest to use a for loop for this -> it will be much safer

Comment: when I add message++ it's giving me a warning ' lvalue required as increment operand'

Comment: `int i = 0;
for(i=0 ; i<50 && mesage[i] !='\n'; i++)
{
       ch = message[i];
       ch += shift;
       putchar(ch);
}
`

Comment: See [Using `sscanf()` in loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of things with your code
a) you have ";" at the end of your `while`
b) you always reading only the first character inside the `sscanf`
thats why you are in the infinite loop.
I would suggest to replace while with the `for` loop like shown below.

`scanf` automagically appends'\0' to the end of the string.

```
int i;
for(i=0 ; i<50 && mesage[i] != '\0'; i++) 
{ 
    ch = message[i]; 
    ch += shift; 
    putchar(ch); 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the encrypted message but with lots of characters after it.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrongly using `sscanf`. It will always read only the first character.

Try this to achieve what you want.

```
int i=0;
while(i<strlen(message))
{
    ch=message[i++];
    ch += shift;
    putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but is there any reason why you can use 'fscanf' to go through each character on a file but not 'sscanf', which is suppose to do the same thing but for a string?

Comment: @tadm123 `fsacnf` is sued to work with `FILE`S see reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ .

Comment: I know, that's what I'm saying @user3351949. I thought that using sscanf for a string was equivalent to using fscanf for a file.

Comment: `sscanf` is basically used to retrieve information from a `string` in a specific format. See use of sscanf here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: @tadm123 Well it is not, when reading from file, it has a pointer to the place you are reading/writing (don't remember it's name it) and it increments that pointer after you are reading. for string it doesn't have that pointer you should manage it your self.

Comment: I see. My book doesn't really go into lots of detail in how to use sscanf, thanks for the link guys.