# How to read lines with different formats

Tags: c, string, input, format

I have an input file with the following form

```
i 176064 Patterson Denise 8.58 11 DEN 15788 
q 188464
ra 148702 167443
a  73131
d 163464
f 6.00
ct 73131 PHY
b 3
p 15703
pe
m 144626 6.51 8
e
```

The first character in each line[i,q,ra,a...] represents an code to a function , while the rest are values that I must store into variables,depending on that code. What's the best way to achieve this ? I have been thinking about using fscanf but each line does not have a specific format, the format itself depends on the code [i,q,ra,a,b..]

Comment: With `strtok`. Read the lines with `fgets` and examine each token, to decide how to proceed.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use anything like fscanf.  Absolutely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Note that some of the 'codes' are multiletter codes, so it is the first 'word' rather than the 'first character' that represents the code to a function.  Since the `scanf()` family of functions don't care about lines, you can't use them to do the file input.  You need to read the lines (`fgets()` for example) and then analyze them (`sscanf()` may be OK — check [Using `sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops), for example).

Answer (score 1):

To read a *line*, use `fgets()`

```
char buffer[100];
while (fgets, buffer, sizeof buffer, istream) != NULL) {
```

Then scan the line against the various formats, each ending with `" %n"`.  `"%n"` records the scan position, if it got that far.  Additional tests could check for extraneous extras character starting at `n`.

```
  int num1, num2, num3;
  char last[sizeof buf];
  char first[sizeof buf];
  char code[sizeof buf];
  double rate;
  int n = 0;
  //               v..v..v..v...v..v..v spaces optional here
  sscanf(buffer, "i %d %s %s %lf %d %s %d %n",
    &num1, last, first, &rate, &num2, code, &num3, &n);
  if (n) {
    Handle_i();
    continue;
  }
  sscanf(buffer, "q %d %n", &num1, &n);
  if (n) {
    Handle_q();
    continue;
  }
  sscanf(buffer, "ra %d %n", &num1, &num2, &n);
  if (n) {
    Handle_ra();
    continue;
  }
  sscanf(buffer, "e %n", &n);
  if (n) {
    Handle_e();
    continue;
  }
  ...
  fail();
}
```

As each format begins with a unique letter pattern, the `sscanf()` will quickly exit on mis-match.

Alternative, code could parse out the initial letters for a slightly more efficient decision tree.  Suspect profiling will show little performance difference.

As with any complex format, consider how one would *maintain* the code and it is bound to evolve.

Comment: ok i got this , can you explain me once again what the n integer exactly does ?

Comment: ok i got this , can you explain me once again what the n integer exactly does ?

Comment: @EugG `int n = 0;` gives `n` the initial value of 0.  `sscanf(buffer, "... %n",
 .... &n);` saves into `n` the offset of the scan of the string `buffer[]` at that point in the scan.  If the scan never reaches the `"%n"` because of an earlier mis-match in the scan, `n` is not changed.