# How to copy contents from one file to another word by word in C?

Tags: c, file, copy, printf, scanf

I know how to copy contents from one file to another character by character, but I am supposed to do it word by word. I tried this code, but when I run this, my output file ends up having each word on a new line. How am I supposed to copy contents from one file to another (as is) word by word?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Error checking
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please print two arguments");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* input = argv[1];
    char* output = argv[2];
    char buffer[4096];

    FILE* fp_open = fopen(input, "r");
    if(fp_open == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file");

    FILE* fp_write = fopen(output, "w");
    if(fp_write == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open output file");

    while(fscanf(fp_open, "%s", buffer) == 1)
    {
        fprintf(fp_write,"%s\n", buffer);
    }

    fclose(fp_open);
    fclose(fp_write);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I am only allowed to use `fscanf("%s")` for reading from an input file.

P.S. I also know that it is inefficient way to do it, but this is what I am supposed to do.

Comment: End your error messages with a newline.  Include the name of the unopenable file in the error message.  Do not continue to use the unopened files if they fail to open.  For most purposes, you can't use `sscanf()` if spacing between words matters, or if you need to track newlines accurately.  If you're only allowed to use `%s` and not also `%c` or something similar (`getc()` for example), then you're stuck — you can't tell what sort of space character separated the words because you're not allowed to use the tools that would let you find out.

Comment: The formatting: noted. But is there no way to do it? Like say first get an entire line and then start scanning it word by word and then separating them by spaces etc?

Comment: Yes; there are ways to do it with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) on POSIX-ish systems), and then using 
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) in a loop (see [How to use `sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)).  But if you're stuck with `fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)` as the only allowed input mechanism, then I think you are hosed.

Comment: Do you happen to know any website or stackoverflow question that has an implementation that uses fgets() alongside sscanf()?

Comment: The linked question shows how to process a line once you've read it.  There isn't much magic to `char line[4096]; while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0) { …code using sscanf to analyze line… }`.  I don't have a specific question to point you at; that much is too routine for me to have any one question to point at — there are probably thousands that could be cited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the request is to read the string using fscanf only, use the following logic :

```
char c;
char tmpbuffer[100], buffer[1000];

fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
while(fscanf(fp,"%s",tmpbuffer)!=-1)
{
strcat(buffer,tmpbuffer,strlen(tmpbuffer));
while((c = fgetc(fp)) == " ")
{
strcat(buffer,&c,1);
}
fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
}
```

here the buffer contains the entire string in a line so you can write the entire line into the output file.