# C - Checking for errors in file

Tags: c, file, input, error-handling, io

I'm trying to get some ideas how to check for errors or mistypes in my data file.
The errors are made by me, intentionally.

> My file looks like this
>
> **Name HouseNr City Country number**(how many sports) **Sport1 Sport2 SportN**
>
> Carl Lincoln42 Houston USA 2 Basketball Football

```
while(fscanf(fData, "%s %s %s %s %d", (person + i)->name,
    (person + i)->adr.houseNr, (person + i)->adr.city, (huvi + i)->adr.country,
    &(sport + i)->sportCount) == 5)
{
    for (j = 0; j < (person + i)->sportCount; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fData, "%s", (person + i)->sportName[j]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Now what I don't grasp is, how should I check for errors in that file.

Let's assume that `number`'s value is higher than that of the `SportN`.

This would mean that it scans other person's details as *SportName*

How should I tackle this? Change some code (please, some suggestions) or change the way I store my data?

Comment: Your conditions must take care of number and new line, for example

Comment: By errors I mean, if I type 5 in Number, but I only have 2 SportNames.

Comment: Is the data in the file *line based*? Then a good start is to read line by line, and parsing each line separately.

Comment: @LPs How to check for new line in fscanf? Is it even possible?
@ Some programmer dude And if I should go the line by line way, how can I use sscanf to read the strings I want? I don't have fixed amount of strings

Comment: If you want the validation to be based on lines of data, then using `fscanf()` directly is wrong — it doesn't care about where newlines occur.  It is simply the wrong tool for line-based processing where there may be errors.  You need to read lines with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)
(or perhaps POSIX's [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and then perhaps parse the result with
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Comment: @KarlJoonasVolke You can have a look at the `%[` format specifier to read lines. Something like: `char line[1000];  if(fscanf(fData, "%[^\n]%*c", line) != 1) { /* fscanf failed or EOF */ }` and then `sscanf` the line

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any idea how should I use sscanf when I dont know how many strings it should read? *Name HouseNr City Country* is always there, but after *number*, it depends on the *number* how many strings it reads

Comment: See [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)  Use `%n` to identify where the number of sports ends, then use the technique in that question to read the sports in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@SomeProgrammerDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253847/c-checking-for-errors-in-file#comment71665610_42253847), it is much better to read the file line by line and parse each line accordingly.

You can use the `%[` format specifier to read lines from the file. This can be achieved by using `%[^\n]` which tells `*scanf` to scan everything until a `\n` (or EOF, whichever comes first). Of course, it *doesn't* scan in the `\n` and as `%[^\n]` will *fail if the first character to be read is a `\n`*, you'll have to get rid of the newline after each line. This can be achieved by using a `%*c` right after the `%[^\n]`. It tells `*scanf` to read and discard a character.

Now that you've read the line, its time to parse it. The `sscanf` function along with the help of the `%n` format specifier can be used for this.

```
char line[1000];
int i = 0;
while(fscanf(fData, "%[^\n]%*c", line) == 1)
{
    int offset;
    if(sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %d%n", (person + i)->name,
    (person + i)->adr.houseNr, (person + i)->adr.city, (huvi + i)->adr.country,
    &(sport + i)->sportCount, &offset) != 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line '%s'\n", line);
        i++;
        continue; /* Move on to next line */
    }
    bool valid = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < (sport + i)->sportCount; j++)
        if(sscanf(line + offset, "%s%n", (person + i)->sportName[j], &offset) != 1)
        {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    char dummy[100];
    if(sscanf(line + offset, "%s", dummy) == 1)
        valid = false;

    if(valid)
        printf("Good input for line '%s'\n", line);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of items in '%s'\n", line);
    i++;
}
```

<sup><sub>Untested Code ↑</sub></sup>

Comment: That is amazing, thank you! I now know how to use sscanf's power.