# 2d array output values incorrect

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, input, output

I have this code and have no idea why my output is incorrect. I'm used to C++ not C.

Run using: ./sudoku.o < inputfile

```
int row = 8;
int col = 8;
int puzzle[row][col];

for (int r = 0; r < row; r++){
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++){                                                      
      scanf("%d", &puzzle[r][c]);
    }
}
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++){
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++){
        printf("%d", puzzle[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

this is my input

```
827154396 
965327148
341689752
593468271
472513689
618972435
786235914
154796823
239841567
```

and this is the output I'm getting

```
-132765-84896035232594-208491627232765-208491623232765
00-84896120832594-84897084832594-85115713632594
10-848970848325941000
10-8489612083259400-208491648032765
1700966438000-84896035232594-208491641632765
-20846176001-208491643232765-163754450041951850
-1000-85506816832594-84897220032594
0000-20849160083276500
```

Comment: You've not checked the return value from `scanf()`.  You should.  (You'd use `if (scanf("%d", &puzzle[r][c]) != 1) { …report error… }`).

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: However, your real problem is that you want to read 1-digit numbers, but your code reads 9-digit numbers until you run out of input.  You need to use `"%1d"` to limit the input to single digits.  If you tested the result from `scanf()`, you'd find out about the trouble because it would say EOF long before your input loops were complete.

Comment: Yes just Make Sure With Your data type and than write %d or whatever

Comment: The posted code can't produce the said output. Have you posted it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, you should check that `scanf()` is successful (in this context, returns 1), and you need to make sure it reads only single digits with `"%1d"`.  Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int row = 8;
    int col = 8;
    int puzzle[row][col];

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            if (scanf("%1d", &puzzle[r][c]) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read puzzle[%d][%d]\n", r, c);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            printf("%d", puzzle[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With your data file, the output is (surprise, surprise):

```
82715439
69653271
48341689
75259346
82714725
13689618
97243578
62359141
```

"Ah", you said, "I wanted 9 numbers per line".  But your code doesn't say that; you set `row` and `col` to 8, so you only read 8 numbers per row of the matrix, and only 8 rows.  And the ninth number on the first row of date becomes the first number on the second row of your matrix, etc.

Change the limits to 9 to get the result you really wanted:

```
827154396
965327148
341689752
593468271
472513689
618972435
786235914
154796823
239841567
```

If you want line-by-line input (not necessarily a bad idea), you'd need to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or perhaps POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) to read lines, and then 
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to read the numbers — see [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)