# When using fscanf to parse words, how can I check when I skipped a line

Tags: c, parsing

I'm working on a program that reads text from a file and parses the text to words and manipulates them. I'm parsing with fscanf like that

```
while (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1)    
{
    /*manipulate the text word by word */
    …
}
```

I wanna write next to each word that I find in which line I found it.

Is there a way that I can check when I moved down a line
when using the function `fscanf`?

Comment: `fscanf` does not distinguish lines, in fact most of its format specifiers ignore all whitespace. Try using `fgets` to read each line and then using a string splitting function.

Comment: ...such as `strsep` or `strtok` and its derivatives, if you want to parse words.

Comment: `fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word)` skips `'\n'` in various places:  Leading `" "` and maybe `"*c"`.  Use `fgets()` to read a _line_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The soundest advice is to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or perhaps POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines and then consider using 
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to parse each line.  You will probably need to consider [how to use `sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).  There are also numerous other options for parsing the line instead of `sscanf()`, such as [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) or the less desirable `strtok()` — or, on Windows, [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx);
[`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html),
[`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html),
[`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html); and other functions that are not as standardized.

If you feel you must use `fscanf()`, then you probably need to capture the trailing context.  A simple version of that would be:

```
char c;
while (fscanf(fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%c", word, &c) == 2)
    …
```

This captures the character after the word, assuming there is one.  If your file doesn't end with a newline, it is possible a word will be lost.  It's also rather too easy to miss a newline.  For example, if the line ends with a full stop (period) before the newline, then `c` will hold the `.` and the newline will be skipped by the next iteration of the loop.  You could overcome that with:

```
char s[33];
while (fscanf(fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%32[ ,.\t\n]", word, s) == 2)
    …
```

Note that the length in the format string must be one less than the length in the variable declaration!

After a successful call to `fscanf()`, the string `s` could contain multiple newlines and blanks and so on.  The `fscanf()` functions mostly don't care about newlines, and the scan set for `s` would read multiple newlines in a row if that's what's in the data file.

If you explicitly capture the status from `fscanf()`, you can be more sensitive to files that end without a newline (or a punctuation character), or that cause other problems:

```
char s[33];
int rc;
while ((rc = fscanf(fp, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%32[ ,.\t\n]", word, s)) != EOF)
{
    switch (rc)
    {
    case 2:
        …proceed as normal, checking s for newlines.
        break;
    case 1:
        …probably an overlong word or EOF without a newline.
        break;
    case 0:
        …probably means the next character is one of comma or dot.
        …spaces, tabs, newlines will be skipped without detection
        …by the leading space in the format string.
        break;
    default:
        assert(0);
        break;
    }
}
```

If you start to care about `!`, `?`, `;`, `:`, `'` or `"` characters — not to mention `(` and `)` — life gets more complex still.  In fact, at that point, the alternatives to `sscanf()` start looking much better.

It is very hard to use the `scanf()` family of functions correctly.  They're anything but tools for the novice, at least once you start needing to do anything complex.  You could look at [A beginner's guide to *not* using `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), which contains much valuable information.  I'm not wholly convinced by the last couple of examples which are supposed to be bomb-proof uses of `scanf()`.  (It is a little easier to use `sscanf()` correctly, but you still need to understand what you're up to in detail.)

Answer (score 1):

Read lines with `fgets()` and then parse them using `sscanf`:

```
char buff[1024];
int lineno = 0;
int offset = 0;
while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp)) {
    lineno++;
    offset = 0;
    while (sscanf(buff + offset, " %32[^ ,.\t\n]%*c", word) == 1)
    {
    /* manipulate the text word by word */

    }
}
```

In second loop you must increase buffer offset appropriately in order to parse line correctly. for this you can use `%n` for example in order to get read bytes.

Comment: But note [using `sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).

Comment: Thanks, I added that. @JonathanLeffler