# Reading from stdin line by line

Tags: c, stdin

I have a basic algorithm i want to try out, and to do so i have a `txt` file with a number of inputs. To do so i redirect the `stdin` to my `input.txt` using the command, in the compiler: `./prog < input.txt`. Here's the mentioned code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void ExA(int n, int VALOR, int *sequencia){
  int i,j,z,soma;
  printf("%d - %d - %d\n",sequencia[0],sequencia[1],sequencia[2]);
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
    for(j=i; j<=n; j++){
      soma = 0;
      for(z=i; z<=j; z++){
        soma = soma + sequencia[j];
      }
      if(soma == VALOR){
        printf("SUBSEQUENCIA NA POSICAO %d\n", i);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("SUBSEQUENCIA NAO ENCONTRADA\n");
}


int main(void){
  int n, i, VALOR;
  int *sequencia = malloc(sizeof(int));
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
  while(read(0, buffer ,sizeof(buffer))){
    sscanf(buffer,"%d %d",&n ,&VALOR);
    if(n == 0 && VALOR == 0){
      return 0;
    }
    else{
      for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        read(0, buffer ,sizeof(buffer));
        sscanf(buffer,"%d",&sequencia[i]);
      }
    }
    ExA(n,VALOR,sequencia);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The main function is responsible for reading from the input file and sending the values to the algorithm `ExA`. In my `input.txt` file i start with the following:

```
3 5
1
3
4
4 5
1
5
4
2
```

However when i print out my array (in the beginning of the `ExA` function) where the numbers should be stored it prints out `1 - 4 - 5` instead of the wanted `1 - 3 - 4`

Comment: Note that `read()` does not deal with strings — it does not add a null terminator to what it reads.  You are, therefore, passing `sscanf()` a byte array and not a guaranteed (null terminated) string.  Also, read pays no attention whatsoever to line breaks.  It reads 4 or 8 bytes at a time (unless you're on a very unusual machine these days) because `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer.'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well i changed both `read()` to `fgets()`  in compliance to your comment. I noticed two things. The first is that when the printed result should be `1 - 3 - 4` it prints `0 - 1 - 3` basically adding a `0` from nowhere. Also when it exits `ExA` and resumes the `While` loop in the main the result is the same, that is, it reads the file from the beggining instead of continuing from where it left of.

Comment: See my edits to my answer — the code shown there isn't fully operational, but you have some explanations for what you see and guidelines on how to fix the remaining problems.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `read()` does not deal with strings — it does not add a null terminator to what it reads.  You are, therefore, passing `sscanf()` a byte array and not a guaranteed (null terminated) string.

Also, `read()` pays no attention whatsoever to line breaks.  It reads 4 or 8 bytes at a time (unless you're on a very unusual machine these days) because `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer.  Assuming you have a 64-bit machine, the first `read()` processes the first 3 lines (`3 5`, `1`, `3` — they happen to be 8 bytes long); the second `read()` gets the second 3 lines (`4`, `4 5`, `1`) and reports appropriately.

You should capture and test the return value from `read()`.  You should print what it gets.  (Partially fixed code — more work to be done to get the program fully working.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void ExA(int n, int VALOR, int *sequencia)
{
    int i, j, z, soma;
    printf("%d - %d - %d\n", sequencia[0], sequencia[1], sequencia[2]);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            soma = 0;
            for (z = i; z <= j; z++)
            {
                soma = soma + sequencia[j];
            }
            if (soma == VALOR)
            {
                printf("SUBSEQUENCIA NA POSICAO %d\n", i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("SUBSEQUENCIA NAO ENCONTRADA\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, VALOR;
    int *sequencia = malloc(sizeof(int));
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    while (read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
    {
        sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &n, &VALOR);
        if (n == 0 && VALOR == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int nbytes = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                printf("Read [%.*s]\n", nbytes, buffer);
                buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
                sscanf(buffer, "%d", &sequencia[i]);
            }
        }
        ExA(n, VALOR, sequencia);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given the input shown in the question, I get the output:

```
Read [4
4 5
1
]
Read [5
4
2
]
[]
4 - 5 - 5
SUBSEQUENCIA NA POSICAO 1
```

This much work cleans up the code — and explains some of the odd result you were getting.  It doesn't make full use of the space allocated (which is bigger than `sizeof(buffer)`, so the `buffer[nbytes] = '\0';` assignment is within bounds of the array.  It reads the same value repeatedly in the `sscanf()` call because you don't tell it to read from different locations in the string. If you need to read multiple values from a buffer using `scanf()`, read the answers about [How to use `sscanf()` in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)

You should consider using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or maybe POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines.  If you're sure the data is clean, you could even use [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) directly, but it is usually better to read lines and then parse them with `sscanf()`.

If the exercise requires you to read with the `read()` system call, then you will have to work out a scheme where you read a buffer full of data and dole the contents out in chunks.