# Strange characters when writing to csv files using fprintf in C

Tags: c, csv, printf, scanf

I am trying to insert First Name, Last Name and Phone Number using fprintf to a CSV file.
But after the insertion additional strange characters and commas are being inserted at the end of each line, and while reading the file it is creating problems.

Following is my code:

```
FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filePath, "r");
    int i = 0;
***** Writing *****
FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.csv", "a");
    fprintf(fp,"%s %s ,%s\n", firstname, lastname , phone_number);
```

***** Reading *****

```
while(!feof(fp)){   
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s,%s", phone_directory[i].First_Name, phone_directory[i].Last_Name, phone_directory[i].Phone_Number);
        printf("%s %s,%s\n", phone_directory[i].First_Name, phone_directory[i].Last_Name, phone_directory[i].Phone_Number);
        i=i+1;
}
```

***** Input ******

```
//First Entry

abc xyz,65656565

//Second Entry

uvw efg,6979679679
```

***** Output *****

```
abc xyz,65656565,
, uvw,
efg,6979679679 ,,
 ,
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: `if (fp == NULL) { perror ("file open failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }` Validate, validate, validate. You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). For further help provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are using feof incorrectly:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: But the main issue is while writing to the file additional commas are being added, how to fix that?

Comment: `while(!feof(fp)){` - Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Please read that `fscanf` returns a value as well- Google `man fsanf`

Comment: Also check the return value from `fopen`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fscanf(fp, "%s %s,%s", phone_directory[i].First_Name, phone_directory[i].Last_Name, phone_directory[i].Phone_Number);` to read a string like `abc xyz,65656565`, the second `%s` will read the entire `xyz,65656565` part instead of stopping by the comma.

To avoid this, you can use

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %[^,],%s", phone_directory[i].First_Name, phone_directory[i].Last_Name, phone_directory[i].Phone_Number);
```

`%[^,]` means to keep scanning till but not including a `,` is encountered.

[`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of successful assignments (or `EOF` on error). You can check its return value (which in this case should be `3` if successful) to see if all the variables were assigned values.

```
if( fscanf(fp, "%s %[^,],%s", str1, str2, str3)!=3 )
{
    printf("\nSomething went wrong!");
}
```

To prevent overflow, you might want to specify the filed width in the format string like

```
fscanf(fp, "%49s %49[^,],%49s", str1, str2, str3)
```

if 50 is the size of each character array. The last character would be needed to store the `\0` character.

Also, check the return value of [`fopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) to see if the file was successfully opened or not. It returns `NULL` on error.

For example,

```
if( (fp=fopen('input.txt', 'r'))==NULL )
{
    perror("\nError opening file!");
}
```

And as was suggested in the comments, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) post.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

A problem with `fscanf` & friends is that they will leave the newline in the input buffer
and this is a problem for subsequent calls of `fscanf`, specially if you
mix different conversion specifiers. There is also an error in the way you
stated the format, more on this later in the answer. If you want to know how to
use `sscanf` in a `while`-loop, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).

You should check the return value of `fscanf`, it tells you how many conversions
were done and if `EOF` has been reached:

```
int convs;

while((convs = fscanf(fp, "%s %[^,],%s", s1, s2, s3)) && convs != 3 && convs != EOF)
{
    printf("%s %s,%s\n", s1, s2, s3);
    i++;
}
```

I changed the arguments to `s1`, `s2` and `s3` because you orginal are just too
long and it's hard to read. The idea is what matters.

Here you end the loop when `fscanf` did not convert all three values and when
`fscanf` reached `EOF`. The problem with this is however that it is hard to
recover from errors, because you don't know exactly where it happened. There is
a second problem though, which I explaint in the next part of the answer.

For this reason it is far superior to read the whole line with `fgets` and then
to parse it with `sscanf`. If `sscanf` fails to parse, you can recover and use
other parsing strategies (such as using `strtok`, or `strstr`, etc):

```
char line[1024];

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{
    int convs = sscanf(line, "%s %[^,],%s", s1, s2, s3);
    if(convs != 3)
    {
        // error handling
        // return/exit/use another parsing strategy/whatever
    }
}
```

One problem with `%s,%s` is that for the input `"a,b"`, only one string will be
converted: `"a,b"`. That's because `%s` matches a sequence of non-white-space characters and
`,` is not a white-space, so `scanf` won't stop until it finds a non-white-space
character. That's why I changed it to `"%[^,],%s"` so that the first conversion
matches everything until the comma.