# How to check if user inputs are double in C?

Tags: c

Normally I would use something like this:

```
    double value;
if (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1)
    printf("It's float: %f\n", value);
else
    printf("It's NOT float ... \n");
```

But this time I need to read two numbers at once

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &y);
```

How do I check that?

Comment: If you want to use [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), you check it by *still* checking what the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function returns.

Comment: `scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &y) == 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SRhm mentioned in the comment section, you simply can use:

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &y) == 2
```

to get two numbers from the user input.
A quote from [scanf - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) explain the return value of the function:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled.

scanf will return an **integer** representing the number of variables successfully read from the user input.

Answer (score 0):

[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) has a [good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027339/how-to-check-if-user-inputs-are-double-in-c#comment92956303_53027339).  Unfortunately, this technique won't work if only the second input is a double but you want to distinguish that from the case where both are not doubles.  In order to distinguish different cases, you might want to take in the input as a string by using the `fgets()` function, and then parse the string into different parts separately [using `sscanf()` on the string multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).

Study the C standard library in detail and you'll find many wonderful library functions that can help you do many things.

Comment: Or just insert two `scanf` calls.

Comment: Please: never ever suggest the use of `gets()` on SO (or anywhere else) because [the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: you have a valid point there. I was thinking strictly function right here, but thanks for pointing that out.