# I need a way to read in floats twice in C. Each time ended by <Ctrl>-d

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, eof

I need to read in the coefficients (as floats) of a polynomial and mark the end by ctrl-d. 
Then I need to read in x values and display f(x). Also ending that with ctrl-d.

So far I have tried it with the `scanf` function. Reading the coefficients work well but after typing ctrl-d the first time, scanf will not read in x values.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int count = 0;
    float poly[33];
    while(scanf("%f", &poly[count]) != EOF){   // reading the coeffs
        count++;
    }
    printf("Bitte Stellen zur Auswertung angeben\n");

    float x;
    float res;

    while(scanf("%f", &x) != EOF){   //Here it Fails. Since scanf still sees the EOF from before
        res = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < count; i++){
            res += poly[i-1] * x + poly[i];
        }
        printf("Wert des Polynoms an der Stelle %f: %f\n", x, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `clearerr(stdin);` to clear the EOF and error conditions on standard input, which should allow you to read more data. The design for the input is not very sensible. All else apart, how could you feed the information from a file? — Short answer: you can't!  It gets very tedious writing tests if you always have to type the data from a terminal. Rethink the design. Require all the coefficients for the polynomial to be on one line.  Read the line (`fgets()`, for example) and convert the numbers ([`sscanf()` in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/)). Then read values.

Comment: Or require a count of the coefficients followed by that many coefficients, and then the rest of the input is `x` values to be evaluated.  Or something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-opening `stdin` may work after the first loop

```
freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
```

Or consider [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307136/i-need-a-way-to-read-in-floats-twice-in-c-each-time-ended-by-ctrl-d/56307608#comment99225611_56307136) idea of `clearerr(stdin)`.

---

How about instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to end input (which closes `stdin`), use <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Create a function to read a *line* of `float`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int read_rest_of_line(FILE *stream) {
  int ch;
  do {
    ch = fgetc(stream);
  } while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
  return ch;
}

// Read a line of input of float`s.  Return count
int read_line_of_floats(float *x, int n) {
  bool char_found = false;
  int count;
  for (count = 0; count < n; count++) {
    // Consume leading white-space looking for \n - do not let "%f" do it
    int ch;
    while (isspace((ch = getchar()))) {
      char_found = true;
      if (ch == '\n') {
        return count;
      }
    }
    if (ch == EOF) {
      return (count || char_found) ? count : EOF;
    }
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    if (scanf("%f", &x[count]) != 1) {
      read_rest_of_line(stdin);
      return count;
    }
  }
  read_rest_of_line(stdin);
  return count;
}
```

Above still needs some work concerning edges cases: `n==0`, when a rare input error occurs, `size_t`, handling of non-numeric input, etc.
Then use it whenever `float` input is needed.

```
#define FN 33
int main(void) {
  float poly[FN];
  int count = read_line_of_floats(poly, FN);

  // Please specify positions for evaluation
  printf("Bitte Stellen zur Auswertung angeben\n");

  float x;
  float res;

  while (read_line_of_floats(&x, 1) == 1) {
    res = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
      res += poly[i - 1] * x + poly[i];
    }
    // Value of the polynomial at the location
    printf("Wert des Polynoms an der Stelle %f: %f\n", x, res);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `freopen()` is a heavyweight way to do it, and won't work properly if the input is a file rather than a terminal.  But the input scheme won't work properly in general if it is a file rather than a terminal.