# How can I stop input with newline character

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I am reading a list of numbers separated by spaces. Currently the loop stops when I press Ctrl + Z. I just need to know how to modify the loop to terminate when I hit enter or if it meets the newline('\n') character.

```
    int numArrayCount = 0;
    int num, count = 0;
    int binaryArray[CAPACITY];
    int numArray[CAPACITY];  

    //takes in positive numbers higher than zero and less than 64. 
    //End output with Ctrl+Z

    while (scanf_s( "%d", &num ) == 1) {
        if (num < 64 && num > 0) {
            binaryArray[ count++ ] = base10ToBinary(num);
            numArray[ numArrayCount++ ] = num;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.

Comment: Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56307608/2410359) for `float`.  Key is to read the potential leading white-space before `scanf("%d"...)` looking for a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way, because `scanf` and friends are only a *poor man's parser*. As long as you have values separated with an arbitrary number of *space* characters (space, tab, return, linefeed and vtab) and it does not matter what those separators are, `scanf` is fine.

If you want to process lines, and then can parse the content of a line, `fgets` is the way to go. Unfortunately, you cannot repeatedly scan from a string, but you can build nice string parsers with `strtok` or better `strcspn`

Other languages (C++, Java, etc.) or maybe other libraries may have smarter tools. But C was initially build as a low level language...

Answer (score 1):

> How can I stop input with newline character (?)

Look for the `'\n'` with `getchar()` before `scanf( "%d", &num )` as `"%d"` quietly consumes leading white-space including `'\n'`.

```
// concept code
int ch;
while (isspace(c = getchar())) {
  if (c == '\n') return "We are done, \\n"
}
if (c == EOF) return "We are done, EOF"
// put back
ungetc(c, stdin);
if (scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1) return "Non-numeric input";
return "Success";
```

Full solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56307608/2410359) for `float`.

---

An alternative approach uses `fgets()` and then pares the *string*.  This good approach does has trouble with long line management and fails should the *line* of input include an uncommon *null character*.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scanf_s(" %d", &num) == 1) {
```

Insert a space before the `%d` as  it will make the scanf function disregard the input that was leftover from whatever was left in stdin and you won't need that getchar() anymore.

[image]

Comment: The space before `%` only causes the function to filter out *whitespace* but not characters that could not previously be converted, such as `'a'`. But most format specifiers (except notably `%c` and `%[]`) filter whitespace anyway, so it's not necessary here.

Comment: The edit shows you are typing `Enter` after each number. But the question asks how to terminate when the first `Enter` or `'\n'` is found.

Comment: Yup, that's true I complety misread it... @WeatherVane is correct.