# Getting the offset from sscanf while reading a string in a loop in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a string using `sscanf()` in a loop but the offset is zero. What is the correct way and is it possible at all to have track of the offset?

In the example here the `offset` should be 5 but the actual value is 0 and I had to set it manually to 5.

```
char line[35]=" -123    1  -25-1245  -12";
char *data=line;
char buf[6];
int offset;
int n,i;

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  if(sscanf(data,"%5[^\n\t]s%n",buf,&offset)==1){
    n=atoi(buf);
    data+=5;//offset;
  printf("n= %5d  offset= %d\n",n, offset);
  }
 }
```

The result is:

```
n=  -123  offset= 0
n=     1  offset= 0
n=   -25  offset= 0
n= -1245  offset= 0
n=   -12  offset= 0
```

Comment: Since the problem is a rogue `s` (potentially originally part of `%s` before the decision was made to use a negated character class), this page can be safely closed as Offtopic: typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misplaced literal `'s'` in the middle of your `sscanf` conversion specification string, which likely does not match and causes `sscanf` to fail before even reaching the `%n`. Remove it.

Comment: Yes, that  was the obvious problem - the extra "s" specifier after the set expression.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a 'scan set' `%[…]` in [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) et al is a complete conversion specification, not a modifier for `%s`.  Your data has no `s` characters in it, so the `sscanf()` fails on matching the literal `s` in your format string, and hence fails to set `offset` because the matching failed.

Use more white space and fewer `s`'s:

```
char line[35] = " -123    1  -25-1245  -12";
char *data = line;
char buf[6];
int offset;
int n, i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (sscanf(data, "%5[^\n\t]%n", buf, &offset) == 1)
    {
        n = atoi(buf);
        data += offset;
        printf("n = %5d; offset = %d\n", n, offset);
    }
}
```

Your question already shows that you know most of what's discussed in [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops)

Comment: yes as @R.. already mentioned I was wrong in adding the s after the set specifier as I was storing the results from sscanf() into a string ... Obviously I have a bad C reference sources.

Comment: It's a common mistake to assume that the scan set notation is a modifier for `%s`; there are numerous questions on SO where that's the problem.  I originally thought it was going to be a simple question of "this is a duplicate of 'How to use `sscanf()` in loops'" but I realized the `s` was causing the trouble.  If your sources conflate `%[…]` with `%s`, then you should look askance at the other information those sources provide — there are likely to be other problems.