# Reading an input file in C

Tags: c, struct, scheduler

I have an assignment to create a CPU scheduler by reading in process information from an input file like this:

```
q 1 tq 4 p1 30 p2 10 p3 24 p4 20 p5 17 p6 4 p7 7 p8 11 p9 8 p10 9 p11 5 p12 6 p13 3 p14 2 p15 1
q 2 tq 5 p1 1 p2 2 p3 2 p4 9 p5 8 p6 5 p7 12 p8 11 p9 15 p10 1 p11 4 p12 8 p13 22 p14 21 p15 30
q 3 tq 30 p1 30 p2 10 p3 24 p4 20 p5 17 p6 4 p7 7 p8 11 p9 8 p10 9 p11 5 p12 6 p13 3 p14 2 p15 1
```

where `q x` is "ready queue x", `tq y` is time quantum y and the rest in the line is in the format `pv w`, where `pv` is p1, p2, p3,..., p15 and are the process names and `w` is the CPU burst time. each queue are to be read from the same input file and stored in separate arrays of `struct` that contains the time quantum, process name and the CPU burst time:

```
struct process{
       char name[4];
       int cputime;
       int timequantum;
};
```

How would I accomplish this? 
I should mention that I have only just started with this C course and have never been taught how to read input files in C.

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? Where's the [mcve] of your attempt? And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you running into problems?  It looks like you need to read the lines with `fgets()` and then carefully scan the line [using `sscanf()` in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).  When you've got a concrete problem (other than the absence of an element name for your `char[3];` line – should that be `char procid[3];` (though it needs to be 4 to be safe for `p12` etc)), then we  can help.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your response. I have only started to study C, and we have not been taught how to read input files at all, which is why I am so confused at the assignment and why they asked us to read input files. So I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Start by writing the hello world program. Solve the problem without reading the file (just hard code the data). You will learn as you go.

Comment: @johnelemans yep, I have just created 3 arrays of structs with hard coded data, so that i can at least write the rest of the program. It's just the reading input file I am stuck on at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you should show (a subset of) the code you use to hard-code the arrays.  You must have some extra structure, even if it is just three named arrays (possibly dynamically allocated with `malloc()`?) to hold the three queues worth of data.  Are you sure you only ever have to worry about 3 queues?  Note that the time quantum is a property of the queue more than the processes within the queue.

Comment: @Pengibaby "_I have just created 3 arrays of structs with hard coded data_". A good first step; well done. Now back-up a step and hard-code some strings (or, possibly, an array of strings) that hold the three lines of data, one string per line (e.g. `char* inp[3]; inp[0] = "q 1 tq 4 p1 30 p2 10 p3...";`. Then read up (by searching the web) on how `sscanf()` works, and explore ways of converting each string in turn into the arrays of structures you already have.