# Convert hexadecimal EBCDIC to character EBCDIC (iseries AS400)

Tags: c, ibm-midrange

I've this command that converts a character EBCDIC to Hexadecimal on my Iseries (AS400) and it works perfect.

```
sprintf((char*)(codeHex),"%02X", input[loop]);
```

Now, I would like to do the opposite command, I mean.. from an hexadecimal code, convert it to a character EBCDIC, and move it to a string char. How can I do it?

Now the info that I recieve has this format:

```
char input[300] ="0x004C0x004F0x00430x004B0x00450x00440x0000..."; 
sprintf((char*)(VariableCharacterEBCDIC),"?..", input[loop]);
```

Regards,

Comment: The counterpart to `printf()` is `scanf()`.

Comment: See [How to use `sscanf()` in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).  Note that you'll need to be careful and/or clever to avoid having `sscanf()` read `0x004C0x…` as hex constant 0x004C0. You'll probably need `%6x` to limit the data read.

Comment: Assuming you can be sure to have an even number of hex digits and you want to convert two hex digits each to a character value, I suggest to implement a loop that (after skipping the `"0x"`) copies 2 characters each from your input to a temporary string and uses `strtol` (if necessary with pre-checking or error handling) to convert it as a base 16 number until you reach the end of the input string.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than building your own function, why not use the functions built into the MI level of the OS..

[Convert Hex to Character (CVTHC)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzatk/CVTHC.htm)

[Convert Character to Hex (CVTCH)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzatk/CVTCH.htm)

They are easily callable from any language on the IBM i, including C.

Note the naming/description is a little wonky, here's a cheat sheet...
CVTHC - Convert to Hex  'A' => 'C1'
CVTCH - Convert to Character 'C1' => 'A'

The RPGLE prototypes look like so:

```
dcl-pr tohex extproc('cvthc');                 
  hexresult char(65534) options(*varsize);     
  charinp char(32767) const options(*varsize); 
  charnibbles int(10) value;                   
end-pr;                                        

dcl-pr fromhex extproc('cvtch');               
  charresult char(32767) options(*varsize);    
  hexinp char(65534) const options(*varsize);  
  hexlen int(10) value;                        
end-pr;
```

So for C, you're passing a couple of char pointers and an integer.  I just don't recall the C equivalent of `extproc('cvthc')`

**edit - C prototypes courtesy of Player1st**

```
void cvthc(char* hexresult, char* charinp, int charnibbles); 
void cvtch(char* charresult, char* hexinp, int hexlen);
```

Comment: No need for any extproc.  `void cvthc(char* hexresult, char* charinpt, int charnibbles);` and `void cvtch(char* charresult, char* hexinp, int hexlen);` will work just fine.  Feel free to update your answer with this.

Comment: @Player1st done...thank you... my C experience was a long time ago.  Isn't there a way to use an alternate name in C?

Comment: The typical way is to just use a macro or a typedef to do so.  The IBM i version of C may have some special syntactic sugar for it but I don't know it off the top of my head if it exists.

Comment: Just in case you want it, the syntax for renaming using a macro is `#define fromhex cvtch` and `#define tohex cvtch`.  You would still need the prototype definitions from earlier as well.

Answer (score 1):

The C prototypes are in QSYSINC/MIH, members CVTCH and CVTHC.

For RPG, you need to code your own prototypes.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I don't see them on our V7.4 system.

Comment: Oops, sorry, it's QSYSINC/MIH.