# Extracting values from a formatted string variable in C

Tags: c

I have input from console in this exact format:

```
|999: Hello! Jan 20 15:00, 875: Hi! Jan 20 17:00, ...........|
```

- The number of whitespaces doesn't matter ( |999: Hello!...| is the same as |999   : Hello! ...| )
- I don't know how many messages there are "999: Hello! Jan 20 15:00" = one message

and I used getline() function to get this whole string as char array variable. The problem now is that I need to extract variables from this string, for example:

```
char USER_ID = 999;

char *MESSAGE = "Hello";

char MONTH[3] = "Jan";

int HOUR = 15;

int MIN = 0;
```

I want to add them to array, that's why I'm asking just about one of them.

I tried using sscanf, but it doesn't work. I even tried not using getline() in the first place and using scanf() insted, but to no avail. How can I do this in C? The only option I can think of is using for loops (run till encounter whitespace, assign, repeat), but that would be terribly slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using for loops to see if it is actually terribly slow.

Comment: @MikeCAT the input can be thousands of charactes long, do you think it won't slow down the program?

Comment: Thousands of characters is not very much. Use awk or grep and see how fast they run on your input - your program should be able to do the same.

Comment: @CarlNorum Alright, I will try for loops then :) I was just hoping there's a simpler solution using built-in functions of C.

Comment: You only  need a single loop. Plus some state.

Comment: If the date format is Jan 01 on dates < 10 its easy to get the last 3 entries by doing a substring. But if you have Jan 1 you are lost

Comment: I would use `strtok()` with a different delimiter string for each of the parts. I would have to assume that the text of every message ends in `!`

Comment: Post an example of the _last_ record too.  Need to see how things end.

Comment: Your code uses `char MONTH[3]` to store the month's 3 characters.  Is using `char MONTH[4]` OK to store the month as a _string_?

Comment: Concerning the `MESSAGE` part, can it contains spaces like `"Hello World"` or is it a space-less message? If it can contains spaces, what makes for the end of this field -  it could be the entire rest of input then?

Answer (score 0):

#### Pass 2 — An arbitrary number of comma-separated messages per line

The question and some of the commentary is ambiguous about the meaning of 'message'.  One of the fields in the input is designated 'message' (`MESSAGE` in the question, but there's no need to shout), but a sequence of 6 data fields (number, greeting, month, day, hour, minute) is also designated as a message.  The Pass 2 rewrite of the Pass 1 code (below) designates the word such as `Hi!` or `Hello!` as the greeting.  Since the sample data has not changed, I am assuming that the greeting portion is a single word with no spaces in it.  As noted in the Pass 1 commentary, if the greeting can contain blanks, then life gets very messy.

It requires a little care in the format string, but the line shown in the question can be parsed with `sscanf()` easily enough, as long as the greeting is a single 'word' — a sequence of non-blank characters.

This answer builds on the ideas in [How to use `sscanf()` in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).

This revised code assumes that a line of input consists of:

- an initial `|` to mark the start of the line.
- a series of one or more comma-separated messages, each of which contains 6 fields (number, greeting, month, day, hour, minute).
- a final `|` to mark the end of the line.

The code uses structures, pointers, and POSIX `getline()`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAX_INFO = 64 };

struct info
{
    int     user_id;
    char    greeting[32];
    char    month[4];
    int     day;
    int     hour;
    int     minute;
};

static size_t parse_line(const char *buffer, size_t num_left, struct info *data);
static void print_info(size_t i, const struct info *data);

int main(void)
{

    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    struct info data[MAX_INFO];
    size_t num_left = MAX_INFO;
    struct info *next_data = data;
    int    length;

    while (num_left > 0 && (length = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        assert(length > 0);
        buffer[length - 1] = '\0';
        printf("[%s]\n", buffer);
        if (buffer[0] != '|')
            break;
        size_t num_read = parse_line(buffer + 1, num_left, next_data);
        printf("Read: %zu\n", num_read);
        if (num_read == 0)
            break;
        next_data += num_read;
        num_left -= num_read;
    }
    free(buffer);

    size_t num_used = MAX_INFO - num_left;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_used; i++)
        print_info(i, &data[i]);

    return 0;
}

static size_t parse_line(const char *buffer, size_t num_left, struct info *data)
{
    char   marker;
    int    offset = 0;
    size_t num_read = 0;
    int    rc;

    while (num_read < num_left &&
           (rc = sscanf(buffer, "%d : %31s %3s %d %d : %d %c%n",
                        &data->user_id, data->greeting, data->month, &data->day,
                        &data->hour, &data->minute, &marker, &offset)) == 7 &&
           (marker == ',' || marker == '|'))
    {
        num_read++;
        if (marker == '|')
            break;
        buffer += offset;
        offset = 0;
        data++;
    }
    if (rc != 7 || (marker != ',' && marker != '|'))
        printf("rc = %d, marker = '%c'\n", rc, marker);
    return num_read;
}

static void print_info(size_t i, const struct info *data)
{
    printf("Info[%zu]: %d [%s] (%s %2d %.2d:%.2d)\n",
           i, data->user_id, data->greeting, data->month, data->day, data->hour, data->minute);
}
```

As noted in the commentary on Pass 1, not all the spaces in the format string are necessary — those before a `%d` or `%s` conversion specification could be omitted.  The code in the main program is responsible for skipping the initial `|` — it would be possible and probably even sensible to move that checking into the `parse_line()` function.

Data file:

```
|999: Hello! Jan 20 15:00, 875: Hi! Jan 20 17:00|
| 666  :   Beast    Nov  20  13 :  17   ,   617 :  Squadron Jul  31  08 : 14 ,  314159 :   Pie Nov 26 00:00 |
|667: Beast Nov 21 14:18,618:Squadron Jul 22 9:15,314159:SweetiePie Nov 27 01:01|
|0:Short Dec 25 08:00|
```

Example output:

```
[|999: Hello! Jan 20 15:00, 875: Hi! Jan 20 17:00|]
Read: 2
[| 666  :   Beast    Nov  20  13 :  17   ,   617 :  Squadron Jul  31  08 : 14 ,  314159 :   Pie Nov 26 00:00 |]
Read: 3
[|667: Beast Nov 21 14:18,618:Squadron Jul 22 9:15,314159:SweetiePie Nov 27 01:01|]
Read: 3
[|0:Short Dec 25 08:00|]
Read: 1
Info[0]: 999 [Hello!] (Jan 20 15:00)
Info[1]: 875 [Hi!] (Jan 20 17:00)
Info[2]: 666 [Beast] (Nov 20 13:17)
Info[3]: 617 [Squadron] (Jul 31 08:14)
Info[4]: 314159 [Pie] (Nov 26 00:00)
Info[5]: 667 [Beast] (Nov 21 14:18)
Info[6]: 618 [Squadron] (Jul 22 09:15)
Info[7]: 314159 [SweetiePie] (Nov 27 01:01)
Info[8]: 0 [Short] (Dec 25 08:00)
```

#### Pass 1 — Two messages per line

It requires a little care in the format string, but the line shown in the question can be parsed with `sscanf()` easily enough as long as the 'message' never contains any blanks.  (If the message can contain blanks, it is messy to parse regardless of whether you use `sscanf()` or any other technology.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "|999: Hello! Jan 20 15:00, 875: Hi! Jan 20 17:00|";

    struct info
    {
        int     user_id;
        char    message[32];
        char    month[4];
        int     day;
        int     hour;
        int     minute;
    } info[2];
    int rc;

    if ((rc = sscanf(data, "|%d : %31s %3s %d %d : %d , %d : %31s %3s %d %d : %d |",
                &info[0].user_id, info[0].message, info[0].month, &info[0].day, &info[0].hour, &info[0].minute,
                &info[1].user_id, info[1].message, info[1].month, &info[1].day, &info[1].hour, &info[1].minute)) != 12)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops: sscanf() failed (rc = %d)!\n", rc);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Info[%d]: %d [%s] (%s %2d %.2d:%.2d)\n",
           0, info[0].user_id, info[0].message, info[0].month, info[0].day, info[0].hour, info[0].minute);
    printf("Info[%d]: %d [%s] (%s %2d %.2d:%.2d)\n",
           1, info[1].user_id, info[1].message, info[1].month, info[1].day, info[1].hour, info[1].minute);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Info[0]: 999 [Hello!] (Jan 20 15:00)
Info[1]: 875 [Hi!] (Jan 20 17:00)
```

Not all the spaces in the format string are necessary — those before `%d` or `%s` conversion specifications could be omitted.  You could add a space before the first `|`, and the last space and last `|` are also superfluous — you'll never know if they were matched.  If you needed to find out, you could do so by adding `%n` after the final `|` and adding an extra argument `&offset` (defined as `int offset = 0;`) as the final argument to the call of `sscanf()`.  You'd need to check that `offset` was not zero after the call; if it is still zero, the scanning failed on the last characters (there wasn't a `|` after the last minute value).

Comment: Yes, I know how to use structures :) your solution is one of those I tried, but the problem is that I don't know how many "messages" there will be in the input

Comment: You should have shown what you tried and stated that your problem was that there could be multiple words in the message, and illustrated it in your sample data.

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify the question!

Comment: Answer revised with 'Pass 2'.  You didn't show any multi-word greeting in the data, so this code doesn't attempt to deal with multi-word greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input format is consistent and well-behaved, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 20 // maximum message length, however long that needs to be

#define EXPAND(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) EXPAND(x) 
#define MSG_FMT STRINGIFY(MESSAGE_LENGTH) // I'll explain this below

int main( void )
{
  int user_id, day, hour, minute;
  char message[MESSAGE_LENGTH+1], month[4];
  char c, p;

  /**
   * If the next non-whitespace character is a '|', start processing the record
   */
  if ( scanf( " %c", &c ) == 1 || c == '|' )
  {
    /**
     * Process multiple records per line, if necessary
     */
    do 
    {
      /**
       * Read the user id, message, and date.  I'll explain the mechanics
       * of how the message is being read below.  We expect 8 items to
       * be read and assigned.
       */
      if ( scanf( "%d: %" MSG_FMT "[^.,?!:;]%c %3s %d %d:%d %c", &user_id, message, &p, month, &day, &hour, &minute, &c ) == 8 )
      {
        /**
         * Process good input - in this case, we just parrot it back.
         */
        printf( "user_id = %d\n", user_id );
        printf( "date = %s %02d %02d:%02d\n", month, day, hour, minute );
        printf( "message = %s%c\n", message, p );
      }
      else
      {
        /**
         * We didn't get 8 good inputs on the last line.  Handle it
         * by not handling it and exiting.
         */
        fprintf( stderr, "Bad input, bailing out immediately\n" );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      /**
       * Keep processing records as long as the last character in the
       * record is a ','
       */
    } while ( c == ',' );
  }

  /**
   * At this point, the last character we should have read is a '|'; if
   * that's not the case, then the last input was bad.
   */
  if ( c == '|' )
  {
    puts( "All records read successfully" );
  }
  else
  {
    puts( "Saw bad delimiter at the end of the last record" );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If your message can be more than one word, like

```
|888: This is a test. Nov 27 12:20 |
```

then you can't use `%s` to read it - it will stop on the first whitespace character.  Instead, we use the `%[` conversion specifier, but this introduces a new problem - we need a way to indicate the end of the message so that it doesn't try to read the date as well.  We need *some* kind of delimiter between the message and the date, so we're going to use the set of punctuation characters `.,?!:;`.  In this case we're going to store that punctuation character to `p` so we can reproduce the message actually read, but if you decide to use a different delimiter that you *don't* want to save (say `:`), you can consume it without assigning it as follows:

```
 %[^:]%*c
```

That `*` in `%*c` tells `scanf` to read the next character and discard it.  You'll need to change the test from `== 8` to `== 7` in that case.

We also read the first non-whitespace character following the record; if it's a `,`, we read the next record, else we stop.  If it's a `|` character, then we know we read everything correctly.

The `%s` and `%[` conversion specifiers suffer from the same security flaw that `gets` did and that `strcpy` and `strcat` still do - they can't know how big the target buffer is based on the address alone.  We have to specify a maximum field width so that that don't read more characters than their respective buffers are sized to hold.

Unfortunately, unlike `printf`, you can't specify the buffer size as an argument - it has to be hardcoded into the conversion specifier.  With the `month` that's easy, we *know* it's sized to hold a string up to 3 characters long (plus the string terminator), so we just specify `%3s`.

Since the size of the `message` buffer is based on a preprocessor macro, we use some additional preprocessor magic to add it to the conversion specifier.  `MSG_FMT` expands to `STRINGIFY(MESSAGE_LENGTH)`, which expands to `EXPAND(20)`, which expands to `"20"`.  That string is concantenated into the format, so it ultimately reads `%20[^.,?!:;]`.

Just know that if your message string is too long to store, then that will affect how the date, hour, and minute are read, and you'll still most likely have a bad input error, it just won't clobber other memory in the process.