# Count the amount of numbers on each line in a text file

Tags: c, file, numbers, c-strings, counting

I am currently learning C programming (my experience is in Python, Java and Swift). I am trying to count how many numbers are on the first line of a text file.

The text file looks a bit like this:

```
-54 37 64 82 -98 
...
```

I have tried various different ideas that I have had. The first was to check each character in turn for the EOL, and if it wasn't to add 1 to the total. I quickly realised this only works for single digit numbers, and not general integers.

I then tried to use `fscanf` to find the last number on the line, and then rewind and use fscanf to count each number until that last number was found again:

```
int temp;
FILE *fd = fopen("test.txt", "r");

fscanf(fd, "%d\n", &temp);
printf("Last Number on Line is: %d\n", temp);
```

However before I could even write the next logic to count the numbers I realised that this printed `Last Number on Line is: -54` which was not the expected output from the above file example.

At this point I am rather stuck. Searching online mainly returns results on how to count how many lines are in a file due to the similarity of the question.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would probably loop over the characters of the string and have a flag stating whether or not the current position is within a number. Whenever that changes from true to false, increment the counter.

Comment: If you have a pre-determined hard limit on the maximum line length, this is fairly trivial: read the line with `fgets` and then use `strtol` iteratively to parse the input line.  If you don't have such a max line limit, you can try using `getline` (if it's available).  It's a fun exercise to do it with `fgets` and a small buffer that does not hold a full line.  Also fun to read 1 character at a time with a state machine. (eg, you must detect that `-1+5` is not a single value). It is neither fun nor educational to do this with `scanf`.

Comment: I'll give that a try after dinner and see what I come up with, thanks

Comment: You can also use `sscanf` with a string pointer and the format spec `"%d%n"` which will tell you the value and the index it stopped scanning. You can use that to advance the string pointer and work your way along the string extracting numbers.

Comment: Be aware of [the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) — avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have used the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74268115/count-the-amount-of-numbers-on-each-line-in-a-text-file?noredirect=1#comment131120122_74268115) and come up with the following solution:

```
char buffer;
int  temp = 0;
int  row_count = 0;

while((buffer = getc(fd)) != '\n') {
    if (temp == 0 && (isdigit(buffer))) {
        col_count += 1;
        temp = 1;
    } else if (temp == 1 && buffer == ' ') {
        temp = 0;
    }
}
```

This is working fine for me in the context I am using it within, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `fgets` to read a line from the file. Then you can use the function `sscanf` to count the number of numbers in the line.

For example let's assume that you already read a line from the file and store it in the array with name `s`

```
char s[] = "1 12 123 1234 12345\n";
```

Now in a loop you can count the number of numbers for example the following way

```
    size_t count = 0;
    int pos;

    for (const char *p = s; sscanf( p, "%*d%n", &pos ) != EOF; p += pos)
    {
        ++count;
    }

    printf( "count = %zu\n", count );
```

The output of this code snippet will be

```
count = 5
```

If you do not know the maximum size of a record in the file you can dynamically reallocate a character array until `fgets` will read the new line character `'\n'` and then apply the approach with `sscanf`.

Comment: I considered this solution however the array size I would need to contain the line fully is unknown and so I wasn't sure how to initialise the array

Comment: @HarryDay You can dynamically reallocate arrays until the new line character '\n' will be read by the function fgets.

Comment: could you link to a documentation or an example about this? I'm struggling to find it online, thanks

Comment: @HarryDay You can find in the internet the documentation by the keyword fgets.

Comment: You don't need an array to hold the numbers if all you're doing is counting how many there are on the line.  Note that using `fscanf()` et al to find lines is ridiculously hard; using `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` and then analyzing with `sscanf()` is a much better idea.  See also [Using `sscanf()` in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).