# Can I ignore a line started with "#" while reading a file in C?

Tags: c, file, pbm

the following code is used to read a `.pbm` file

```
int **leArquivoImagem(char *nomeImagem, char *tipo, int *lin, int *col)
{
    FILE *arq = fopen(nomeImagem, "r");
    if (arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nErro ao abrir arquivo - leArquivoImagem.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fscanf(arq, "%s", tipo);
    printf("%s\n", tipo);

    //line ignorer here

    fscanf(arq, "%d %d", col, lin);
    printf("%d %d\n", *lin, *col);
    int **mat = alocaMatrizImagem(*lin, *col);
    if (mat == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nErro ao alocar mat imagem - leArquivoImagem.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *lin; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            fscanf(arq, "%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return mat;
}
```

and that's the file I'm reading:

```
P1
5 3
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

but in some cases files can have commented lines, like this:

```
P1
# comment here
5 3
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

or even like this:

```
P1
# comment here
# another comment to ignore
5 3
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

How can I ingore those lines? (Comments are always between the "P1" and the dimensions).

I tried using a buffer with the max line size (2047) in the following codes:

```
char line[2047];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arq) != NULL)
    {
        char *hash = strchr(line, '#');
        if (hash != NULL)
            *hash = '\0';
    }
```

---

```
    char buffer[2047];
    while (fgets(buffer, 2047, arq) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] != '#') {
            break;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    char line[2047];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arq)) {
        if (line[0] == '#') {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indeed you can: you yourself have shown three ways of doing it. Do they not work? Do you have a question about them?

Comment: An irrelavent but related recommendation in your code when reading lines: if the max line size is the max length of text, your buffer size should be `2048` (2047 for text and 1 for the `\0` character)

Comment: JohnKugelman none of they worked, that's the problem.
@YuWea thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: The `continue` version is most likely to be correct.  The `break` version is incorrect; you don't want to stop reading the file because of the comment line.  The other version might be OK if your line processing code handles an empty line cleanly.  Of course, there will be string processing code, probably [using `sscanf()` in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3975236/15168) to process the line.

Comment: @DuartinhoCodes Mixing `fscanf(arq, ...)` with `fgets(,,,, arq)` is a problem.  Best to stop using `fscanf()` until you understand why it it bad.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the suggestion, I will change my code to use only fgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solved my problem. Thanks to Chux for suggesting to use only `fgets()`, YuWea for the buffer size correction, and Jonathan Leffler for suggesting `sscanf()` and `break`.

```
int **leArquivoImagem(char *nomeImagem, char *tipo, int *lin, int *col) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nomeImagem, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) {
        printf("\nErro ao abrir arquivo - leArquivoImagem.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char buffer[2048];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), arq) != NULL) {

        sscanf(buffer, "%s", tipo);
        printf("%s\n", tipo);

        // Ignore all commented lines and get dimensions
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), arq) != NULL) {
            if (buffer[0] != '#') {
                sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", col, lin);
                printf("%d %d\n", *lin, *col);
                break;
            }
        }

        int **mat = alocaMatrizImagem(*lin, *col);
        if (mat == NULL) {
            printf("\nErro ao alocar mat imagem - leArquivoImagem.\n");
            fclose(arq);
            return NULL;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < *lin; i++) {
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), arq);
            char *ptr = buffer;
            for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++) {
                while (*ptr == ' ') ptr++;
                if (*ptr == '\n' || *ptr == '\0') {
                    j--;
                    continue;
                }
                mat[i][j] = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
            }
        }

        fclose(arq);
        return mat;
    }

    fclose(arq);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done those `fgets` calls, you need to check the buffer in case it's not a comment line. You do this with `scanf` rather than the `fscanf` that you would use if comments weren't supported.

```
char line[2047];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arq) != NULL)
{
    char *hash = strchr(line, '#'); /* You might be able to combine this line into the if-statement. */
    if (hash != NULL)
        continue; /* comment line */
    
    sscanf(line, "%d %d", col, lin);
    printf("%d %d\n", *lin, *col);
    int **mat = ....
```

Comment: This will skip a line that contains `'#'`, even if not the first character.  OP's goal is <ignore a line started with "#">

Comment: You aren't checking the return value from sscanf.