# How to handle exception when scanf of integer gets a character

Tags: c, scanf

The following simple program would give an endless loop when the input is a character, though it meant to tell a character from a digit. How to test if `scanf` gets a character when it is supposed to be a digit using the return value of `scanf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  int return_value = 0;

  while (!return_value) {
    printf("Input a digit:");
    return_value = scanf("%d", &n);
  }

  printf("Your input is %d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not an exception. It's a technical problem.

Comment: read all inputs as strings, then check if string is numeric and if so, convert string to number. Use this two functions [isNumeric()](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#C) and [atof()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/).

Comment: @TheDubleM Nice try! But what I really want to know is how to do the job using `scanf`.

Comment: @congliu `scanf` will read form stdin and than you have to process data you get

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is scanf() causing infinite loop in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) pointed in his answer that the character doesn't consumed by `scanf` here and lives in the buffer, on next iteration `scanf` again read the same character and again leave it to the buffer and so on. This results in infinite loop.

You need to consume this character before next iteration. Just place a `getchar()` after the line `return_value = scanf("%d", &n);`

```
return_value = scanf("%d", &n);
while(getchar() != '\n');     // will consume the charater
```

Comment: `getchar()` only consume one character, how to consume all the input characters?

Answer (score 1):

You get an infinite loop because `scanf` doesn't consume the character, so the character will never leave the input buffer.

You can solve it by reading a line with e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then use `sscanf` on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Add second (nested loop ) loop that clears the input buffer before you try to read from it with another scanf.

I haven't done in a long time but it goes like that:
    #include

```
int main() {
  int n;
  int return_value = 0;

  while (!return_value) {
    printf("Input a digit:");
    return_value = scanf("%d", &n);
    // this loop will "eat" every character that's left in input buffer
    while(getchar() !='\n') {
    continue;
    }
  }

  printf("Your input is %d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Basically, any function/method that clears the input buffer after fail will work the same way. Choose one you like the most.

Comment: Edited, it's really simple but that's how I did it when I was starting with C. It's not the shortest way, but it gives you idea what's going on with buffered input and scanf.

Comment: Seems like it stuck after inputting anything

Comment: oh i missed the comparison value, you compare result of getchar with new line character. Damn im C-rusty :)

Answer (score -1):

You should really use TheDubleM's suggestion and check if `buffer` is numeric and if so use atoi on it. In what I put below you will not detect `8f8` as bad input but just read the 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  int return_value = 0;
  char buffer[1024];

  while (!return_value) {
    printf("Input a digit:");
    scanf("%1024s", buffer);
    return_value = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
  }

  printf("Your input is %d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```