# How to check if scanf() worked fine in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to see if user enters 3 correct input. If not the loop ask for input again and again until they correct it correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        int num1,num2;
        char str;
        int check;

        printf("Enter : ");
        check = scanf("%d,%d, %c", &num1, &num2, &str);

        while (check != 3) {

                 printf("Enter : ");
                 check = scanf("%d,%d, %c", &num1, &num2, &str);
        }


}
```

Let's say if I enter`a, 5.4, c` we get an infinite loop. Why is it giving an infinite loop?

Comment: Because the `scanf` does not consume the input if it does not match. So your code is continuously trying to parse the same input (which will never succeed).

Comment: you initialize main to be `int main(void)` and then you dont return a value from main? Where's your `return 0`?

Comment: why don't you use `return` function

Comment: [Why is scanf() causing infinite loop in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)

Comment: @JackWilliams: Technically `main()` doesn't need to explicitly return. A return value of `0` is implied, since C99.

Comment: Instead, use `fgets()` to read the line and then parse  it, maybe with `sscanf()`

Comment: You could simplify your code by moving the first `printf` and `check =` to be inside the loop, and giving an initial value such as `int check = 0;` (or using a do...while loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are far more ways to incorrectly use `scanf` in a loop that proper ones. The primary issue (aside from *input* or *matching* failures that are explained in the man page), is failing to empty the *input buffer* (`stdin` when reading from a terminal) after a failed conversion. (There is also the issue that the user must enter something.) When a user enters text and presses `[Enter]` a `newline` (`'\n'`) is generated and placed in the input buffer to mark the end of line. When you enter `a, 5.4, c`, `'a'` is fine, but `5.4` is not an `int` and the processing fails:

> If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read, and
>   scanf() returns.

When `scanf` returns, it leaves the remaining characters in `stdin` and you loop and attempt to read again. `scanf` attempts to read what is left in `stdin`, processing again fails, and the loop continues endlessly.

In this situation the only way to prevent the indefinite loop is to manually empty the input buffer after you call to `scanf`. Something simple will do:

```
int c;
...
while (...) {
    scanf (...)
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}
```

This will insure you start with an empty buffer on the next iteration. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int num1 ,num2, c;
    char str;

    while (printf ("\nEnter : ") && 
           scanf (" %d, %d, %c%*c", &num1, &num2, &str) != 3) {
        printf ("error: invalid input, required: 'int, int, char'\n");

        /* empty remaining chars from input buffer */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
    }

    printf ("\n num1 : %d\n num2 : %d\n str  : %c\n\n", num1, num2, str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use**

```
$./bin/scanf3

Enter : a
error: invalid input, required: 'int, int, char'

Enter : a, 5.4, c
error: invalid input, required: 'int, int, char'

Enter : 10, 25
error: invalid input, required: 'int, int, char'

Enter : 10, 25, a

 num1 : 10
 num2 : 25
 str  : a
```

*note:* this does not protect against the user entering nothing (just pressing `[Enter]`) and the cursor just sitting there blinking as it waits for input. That is an inherent behavior of `scanf`, part of which is the reason that *line-oriented* input methods (`fgets` or `getline`) are preferable when taking input.

Answer (score -1):

First time  scanf() reads the character then it reads the newline (enter/whitespace character ).This  character is present in the input buffer and is read by the scanf() function.

So clear the buffer before reading the new user input using fflush(stdin).

**EDIT :** Tested in windows VS2013.Sorry i dont have Linux. Windows and Linux define the behaviour of fflush() in different way.If you are using in Windows platform :

```
int main(void) {

    int num1, num2;
    char str;
    int check;

    printf("Enter : ");
    check = scanf("%d,%d, %c", &num1, &num2, &str);

    while (check != 3) {

////Flush the input buffer ////

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter : ");
        check = scanf("%d,%d, %c", &num1, &num2, &str);
    }
```

}

**EDIT :** this will work in all platforms.

Another simple way is to consume the remaining read line by

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

so now

```
int main(void) {

    int num1, num2;
    char str,c;
    int check;

    printf("Enter : ");
    check = scanf("%d,%d, %c", &num1, &num2, &str);

    while (check != 3) {

        ////read the remaining char ////
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

        printf("Enter : ");
        check = scanf("%d,%d, %c", &num1, &num2, &str);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is still generating infinite loop.

Comment: @Pawan i have updated the code