# In C the do while repeats if I enter a character. I need to eliminate that error

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, do-while

This is a **C** program for tic tac toe. It works fine but if you enter a character in your turn, it repeats for infinite time. I know I can't enter a character in %d but that's the task I've been given, that if someone enters a character it should not accept it, and asks for the turn again, like it does when I enter a number other than 1-9.  HELP

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int a, player, winner, row, column, line, go;
  char z;
  do
  {
    char name1[20];
    char name2[20];
    printf("\nEnter Player 1 name");
    scanf("%s", name1);
    printf("\nEnter Player 2 name");
    scanf("%s", name2);
    char board[3][3] =
        {
            {'1', '2', '3'},
            {'4', '5', '6'},
            {'7', '8', '9'}
        };
    winner = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < 9 && winner == 0; a++)
    {
      printf("\n\n");
      printf("\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
      printf("\t-----------\n");
      printf("\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
      printf("\t-----------\n");
      printf("\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
      player = a % 2 + 1;
      do
      {
        if (player == 1)
          printf("\nPlayer %s enter the number of square(from 1 to   9)", name1);
        else if (player == 2)
          printf("\nPlayer %s enter the number of square(from 1 to 9)", name2);
        scanf("      %d     ", &go);
        if (go > 0 && go < 10)
        {
          row = --go / 3;
          column = go % 3;
          break;
        }
      }
      while (go < 0 || go > 9 || board[row][column] > '9' || (go >= 'a' && go <= 'z') || (go >= 'Z' && go <= 'Z'));
      if (player == 1)
        board[row][column] = 'X';
      else
        board[row][column] = 'O';

      if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2]) ||
          (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[2][0]))
      {
        winner = player;
      }
      else
      {
        for (line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        {
          if ((board[line][0] == board[line][1] && board[line][0] == board[line][2]) ||
              (board[0][line] == board[1][line] && board[0][line] == board[2][line]))
            winner = player;
        }
      }

    }
    if (winner == 0)
      printf("\nDRAW");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("\t-----------\n");
    printf("\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("\t-----------\n");
    printf("\t %c | %c | %c \n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
    if (winner == 1)
      printf("player %s \n YOU WON !!!", name1);
    else if (winner == 2)
      printf("player %s \n YOU WON !!!", name2);
    printf("\nDo u want to repeat(Y/N)");
    z = getch();
    system("cls");
  }
  while (z == 'y' || z == 'Y');
  getch();
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Learn [ask], then start with not using street-slang.

Comment: `getch();` and `scanf()` do not play well together.

Comment: removing getch doesnt work too

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the return value of `scanf` to see if it read something.

It will stop reading when it finds a character that cannot be part of a number. The next time through the loop, the offending character will still be there and it fails again. And again.

Comment: i added printf. and it gets like a negative value. it there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Closely related topic: [Why is scanf() causing infinite loop in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)

The reason is that if scanf fails to read the pattern it doesn't empty the input buffer, you have to do it manually.

Comment: how. plz explain. i just learnt C language, not an expert in it. a lil more detail would be great.

Comment: There's plenty of information in the linked topic which also links to this document: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/tutorials/io/io.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `scanf("%d",&some_variable);`, and if the user inputs a number, the scanf function will return 1 and if the user enters a character, it will return 0.

So the following check can be performed

```
if(scanf("%d",&variable_name)==1)
{
    // this means the input is an integer, fine.
}
else
{
   // this means the input is a character, put some error handling here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the man page for scanf and check what error value are you getting. http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf