# Error message check not working in C

Tags: c, calculator

I'm a beginner in programming and I've been trying to make a calculator console app in C for self entertainment, however there has been one minor problem that I thought I could solve easily, but it seems like I'm missing something. I made the system foolproof, as one could say, so you could not type letters instead of numbers and such (I'm bad at explaining, but you get the idea). The problem is that whenever I type the wrong sign and the wrong number B at the same time, both of the error messages appear, which shouldn't happen. I thought it's because of the goto function, which I read isn't very good to use, so I put a check whether an error message has already been shown (bad=1;), which works only with the first number for some reason. What am I doing wrong here?

```
while (1) {
    double a, b, f=1;
    char znak1;
    int bad;

getagin: 
    bad = 0;
    if(scanf("%lf", &a)) printf("");
    else {
        if(bad == 0) printf("Incorrect number, please write the problem again.\n---\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        bad = 1;
        goto getagin;
    }

    scanf(" %c", &znak1);
    char result[32];
    int n = f;
    if (znak1 == '+') printf("");
    else if (znak1 == '-') printf("");
    else if (znak1 == '/') printf("");
    else if (znak1 == '*') printf("");
    else if (znak1 == '^') printf("");
    else {
        if(bad == 0) printf("Incorrect sign, please write the problem again.\n---\n");
        bad = 1;
        goto getagin;
    }

    if(scanf("%lf", &b)) printf("");
    else {
        if(bad == 0) printf("Incorrect number, please write the problem again.\n---\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        bad = 1;
        goto getagin;
    }
    if (znak1 == '+') snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%.*f", n, a + b);
    else if (znak1 == '-') snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%.*f", n, a - b);
    else if (znak1 == '/') snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%.*f", n, a / b);
    else if (znak1 == '*') snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%.*f", n, a * b);
    else if (znak1 == '^') snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%.*f", n, pow(a, b));
    printf("Solved problem: %.*f %c %.*f = %s\n---\n", n, a, znak1, n, b, result);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `goto` to go back to the beginning of the loop, use `continue`.

Comment: The `bad = 1;` assignment doesn't work because when you go to `getagin`, it immediately does `bad = 0;`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code for the proper way to check for numeric input.

Comment: Avoid `spaghetti code`, don't use `goto`.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: E.g input `6 % 2` ==> `3 * 4`. Since `%` is invalid, it returns first, but in this case it is necessary to clear the remaining input `2`. `2` is used as the next first number and `3` is used as the operator.

Comment: And BTW, only Seniors may use `goto`. ;-)

Comment: After your error messages, you set `bad` to 1, then you goto `getagin`.  Now look at the very first statement after `getagin`:  It sets `bad` to 0.  So setting it to 1 before branching there served no purpose.  You just need to think this through, you have all the information you need - you just need to reason it out.

Comment: Thanks everyone, found my problem and solved it.

Comment: Also note that if you ever get an EOF while looking for a newline, you will go into an infinite loop.  Hint:  *Always* check for EOF, and handle appropriately.

Comment: When you have a chain of `else if` statements like this, consider using logical operators instead: `if znak1 == '+' || znak1 == '-' || /* ... */ {}`. In this case, you could also use the standard library function `strchr()` from `string.h`:  `const char *operations = "+-/*^";  /* ... */ if (strchr(operations, znak1) == NULL) { printf("Invalid operation: %c\n", znak1); /* ... */ } else { /* ... */};`