# C program looping infinitely

Tags: scanf

I'm new here
and I'm also very new to programming
I'm trying to make a menu interface that loops back to the beginning after i input something
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int x;
int main()
{MENU:
    printf("Welcome to our menu\n");
    printf("What do you want to do ?\nSelect your option\n\n");
    printf("1. Binary to decimal converter\n");
    printf("2. Lorem ipsum\n");
    printf("3. Lorem ipsum\n");
    printf("4. About us\n");
    printf("5. Quit\n\n");

    printf("Input your option:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("\n");

    if (x==1){
        printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");

        goto MENU;

    }
    else if (x==2){
        printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
        goto MENU;
    }
    else if (x==3){
        printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
        goto MENU;
    }
    else if (x==4){
        printf("About us\n\n");
        printf("Team Members");
        goto MENU;
    }
    else if (x==5){
        printf("Thank you for using this program");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid input");
        goto MENU;
    }


}
```

The problem here now is that whenever I input something other than 1 to 5 the whole program will loop non-stop. Why is that ? What can I do about it ?

Comment: `goto` ?......... `while() { continue}` works also

Comment: The program does what its supposed to do..whats wrong with that?

Comment: 1) Don't use `goto` when you don't have to. 2) replace all those `if-else if` blocks with a single `switch(x)`

Comment: @coderredoc Inputting 1 - 5 works, however anything other than that will cause it to loop non-stop without being able to input anything at all.

Comment: Are you dealing with the new line marker in `scanf`?

Comment: similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)

Comment: "_however anything other than that will cause it to loop non-stop_" The reason is that `scanf` did not consume the input because it didn't see an integer. Therefore better to use `fgets`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The OP is getting infinite loop when alphabetic character is entered. To avoid that you can get string input (maybe `fgets`) and check if all input characters are digit and then convert it to int using `atoi` etc.

Codewise you can do something like this:-

```
char numbuf[MAX_LEN];
int op,success=0;
while( fgets(numbuf,sizeof numbuf, stdin) ){
   if(sscanf(numbuf, "%d",&op) == 1){
       success=1;
       break;
   }else
     fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in input, give right one\n");
}
if( success )
// At this point you are sure that you have an int in `op`
success = 0;
```

Full code will be something like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100
int x;
int main()
{MENU:
    printf("Welcome to our menu\n");
    printf("What do you want to do ?\nSelect your option\n\n");
    printf("1. Binary to decimal converter\n");
    printf("2. Lorem ipsum\n");
    printf("3. Lorem ipsum\n");
    printf("4. About us\n");
    printf("5. Quit\n\n");

    printf("Input your option:");
    char numbuf[MAX_LEN];
    int success = 0;
    while( fgets(numbuf,sizeof numbuf, stdin) ){
       numbuf[strcspn(numbuf, "\n")] = 0;
       if(sscanf(numbuf, "%d",&x) == 1){
         success = 1;
         break;
       }
       else
         fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in input, give right one\n");
    }
    if( success == 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    success = 0;
    if (x==1){
        printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");

        goto MENU;

    }
    else if (x==2){
        printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
        goto MENU;
    }
    else if (x==3){
        printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
        goto MENU;
    }
    else if (x==4){
        printf("About us\n\n");
        printf("Team Members");
        goto MENU;
    }
    else if (x==5){
        printf("Thank you for using this program");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid input");
        goto MENU;
    }


}
```

**Still I don't understand why the infinite loop?**

> `scanf` consumes input if it matches format string. Here it doesn't.
>   So `scanf` stops consuming it. The non-matching input is still in the
>   input buffer. As a result, it is being skipped and you get the propmpt
>   frequently. You can also get rid of this by clearing the input buffer.

Use of `goto` is not something wrong but it generates code that is hard to maintain and debugging is much more difficult. We can use `series of if else` to simple `switch-case` statement that is much more clear to understand. Look at this code to notice these two things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100

int main()
{
    int x;
    while(1){
        printf("Welcome to our menu\n");
        printf("What do you want to do ?\nSelect your option\n\n");
        printf("1. Binary to decimal converter\n");
        printf("2. Lorem ipsum\n");
        printf("3. Lorem ipsum\n");
        printf("4. About us\n");
        printf("5. Quit\n\n");

        printf("Input your option:");
        char numbuf[MAX_LEN];
        int success = 0;
        while( fgets(numbuf,sizeof numbuf, stdin) ){
           numbuf[strcspn(numbuf, "\n")] = 0;
           if(sscanf(numbuf, "%d",&x) == 1){
             success = 1;
             break;
           }
           else
             fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in input, give right one\n");
        }
        if( success == 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        success = 0;
        switch(x){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3: printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
                    continue;
            case 4: printf("About us\n\nTeam Members");
                    continue;
            case 5: printf("Thank you for using this program");
                    exit(0);
            default:printf("Invalid input"); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Jokes apart:

[image]

Comment: See also [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: Suggest `fgets` and `sscanf` and check the return value from `sscanf` which should be `1`.

Comment: That works if you use `x` to match OP, but there is no need to remove the trailing newline. But the `while` needs better flow control, seeing as under it it says `// is OK` but not if `NULL` comes from `fgets`.

Comment: @WeatherVane.: Thanks for the suggestion..please let me know if there is some scope to improve

Comment: It will really help me if I get to know why I am downvoted.

Comment: I find your answer most helpful. Not sure who downvoted it or why.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it simpler by making use of a do while loop and switch case in it.

Try this

```
int main()
{
int x;
do
{
    printf("Welcome to our menu\n");
    printf("What do you want to do ?\nSelect your option\n\n");
    printf("1. Binary to decimal converter\n");
    printf("2. Lorem ipsum\n");
    printf("3. Lorem ipsum\n");
    printf("4. About us\n");
    printf("5. Quit\n\n");

    printf("Input your option:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("\n");

    //Switch statement
    switch(x)
    {
    case 1: printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
            break;
    case 2: printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
            break;
    case 3: printf("This module doesn't exist yet\n\n");
            break;
    case 4: printf("About us\n\n");
            printf("Team Members");
            break;
    case 5: return 0;
    default: printf("Invalid input");
    }
}while(1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the basic problem of non-numeric input stuck in the input buffer. Someone else downvoted.

Comment: Exception handling can be used then.

Comment: I appreciate that you simplified my code (I actually needed that) but it still looping forever xD

Comment: "Exception handling can be used then." -- there is no exception handling in C, yet there are canonical ways of dealing with this problem.