# How to prevent user from inputting char

Tags: c, switch-statement

**On the first run**, it works fine. 
The Program runs the **last chosen case** when you input a **char**

```
int x;
do{
printf("Input a number:");
    scanf("%d", &x);

switch(x){
    case 1: printf("A\n\n");
            break;
    case 2: printf("B\n\n");
            break;
    case 3: printf("C\n\n");
            break;
    case 4: printf("End");
            break;
    default: printf("Invalid.\n");
}

}while(x!=4);
```

how do I prevent this?

Comment: Check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value of `scanf` and if it doesn't return `1` then you will know that either user inputted something not desired by the format specifier or some error occured.

```
if(scanf("%d", &x) != 1){
  fprintf(stderr,"Error occured\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Better solution is to use `fgets` and parse for number using `strtol`. It will give a much more error handling and control over the whole procedure than `scanf` would.

As I said, you can also go for using `fgets` to read a line and then use `sscanf` to parse the integer input. Play a bit with this bare minimum function you will understand what I mean:-

```
#define MAXLEN 50
int f() {
  int v;
  char buff[MAXLEN];
  while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin)) {
    if (sscanf(buff, "%d", &v) == 1 ) {
      return v;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to just skip to the next iteration if an invalid input was given? Using `continue` doesnt work for me. It loops infinitely without asking for input later on.

Comment: @Rishav.: You didn't see me using `continue` did you? That is why I mentioned that use `fgets` it would be easier. Now look here also you can solve the thing - whyit fails here? Becaus ethose bad inputs are still there. Now if you put a consecutive `getchar()` calls removing those bad inputs (easy to consider that they appear in line and we will delete it) then yes it would again wait for good input.

Comment: Great! Thanks I got it.

Answer (score 0):

> The Program runs the last chosen case when you input a char.

This is because when `scanf("%d", &x);` failed it did not updated the variable `x`. `x`still remembers the last chosen good number.

Check the standard [7.21.6.4 The scanf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4).

You can read about behaviour of `scanf`
 [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

On success, the `scanf` returns the number of items successfully read. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens. In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

Knowing that you can check the return value of `scanf` and make appropriate decision. In the program below, bad `scanf` input is treated as `case 4:` and program ends:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;
    do{         
        printf("Input a number:\n");

        if(scanf("%d", &x) != 1){
            printf("Error - END.\n");
            break;
        }

        switch(x){
            case 1: printf("A\n\n");
                    break;
            case 2: printf("B\n\n");
                    break;
            case 3: printf("C\n\n");
                    break;
            case 4: printf("End\n");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid.\n");
        }

    }while(x!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input a number:                                                                                                                                  
0                                                                                                                                                
Invalid.                                                                                                                                         
Input a number:                                                                                                                                  
1                                                                                                                                                
A                                                                                                                                                

Input a number:                                                                                                                                  
2                                                                                                                                                
B                                                                                                                                                

Input a number:                                                                                                                                  
3                                                                                                                                                
C                                                                                                                                                

Input a number:                                                                                                                                  
N                                                                                                                                                
Error - END.
```

Edit:

If OP requires program to continue to run after user bad input, that requires more work.
The naive approach is to replace the `break` with `continue`.

That will not work! Any character that does not match the format string causes `scanf` to stop scanning and leaves the invalid character still in the buffer!

To continue we have to flush the invalid character out of the buffer.

The modified program is given below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int main(){

    int x;
    char c;
    int error = 0;

    do{
        c = '0';

        if(!error)
            printf("Input a number:\n");
        else
            error = 0;

        if(scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        {    
            printf("No letters! Input a number:\n");
            do
            {
                c = getchar();
            }
            while (!isdigit(c));

            ungetc(c, stdin);
            error = 1;

            continue;
        }

        switch(x){
            case 1: printf("A\n\n");
                    break;
            case 2: printf("B\n\n");
                    break;
            case 3: printf("C\n\n");
                    break;
            case 4: printf("End\n");
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid.\n");
        }

    }while(x!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input a number:                                                                                                                             
1                                                                                                                                           
A                                                                                                                                           

Input a number:                                                                                                                             
X                                                                                                                                           
No letters! Input a number:                                                                                                                 
1                                                                                                                                           
A                                                                                                                                           

Input a number:                                                                                                                             
4                                                                                                                                           
End
```

Comment: How do I make it so that the loop doesn't end?

Comment: @Rollo    You mean, does not end when there is an error? Then ` if(scanf("%d", &x) != 1){ continue;}` should do.  Check it.

Comment: It loops printf("Input a number:\n"); infinitely

Comment: @Rollo I will work on your additional question tomorrow. But check this yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code

Comment: @Rollo OK! I tested it and it works for me:         `printf("Input a number:\n");

        char c = '0';
        if(scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        {
            printf("No letters! Input number:\n");
            do
            {
                c = getchar();
            }
            while (!isdigit(c));
            
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            continue;
        }` Could you also check it?  Thanks!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much @sg7!
I have a warning though.. [Warning] implicit declaration of function 'isdigit' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: @Rollo You may want to include more include files: `#include <ctype.h>`