# Sorting an array using functions

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having extreme trouble figuring this code out. I need four functions besides `main()` that: reads the array elements, prints the array elements, sorts the array, and swaps two elements of an array.

I cannot use any structured code (e.g., no `goto`, `break`, `continue`, etc. statements.

I also need to be able to run the program by entering more values than the declared array size which is 10, display an error message and then sort the first 10 values entered anyway. I need to be able to run the program and enter a character and display an error message and flush the bad data and continue reading until end of file or the array is full.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10 //max number of elements is 10

int main()
{   
    void print(const int arr[],int size);
    void sort(int arr[],int size);
    int getArray(int arr[],int max);
    int arr[MAXSIZE]; //array
    int size=getArray(arr,MAXSIZE); //size of array

    printf("The array is:\n");
    print(arr,size);
    sort(arr,size);
    printf("The sorted array is:\n");
    print(arr,size);
}

void swap(int arr[],int i,int j) //swap function
{
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

void print(const int arr[],int size) //print function
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf ("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void sort(int arr[],int size) //sort funtion
{
    void swap(int arr[], int i, int j);
    int min, min_index, i, j;

    for( i = 0; i <= size - 2; i++)
    {
        min = arr[i];
        min_index = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < min)
            {
                min = arr[j];
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        swap(arr, i, min_index);
    }
}

int getArray(int arr[],int max)
{   
    int temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char c;

    printf ("Enter numbers with spaces between them\n");
    scanf ("%i", &temp);
    while ((c = scanf ("%i", &temp)) != EOF || count < max)
    {
        if(c == 0){
            printf ("Invalid character. Please enter the numbers again.\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n');
        } else {
            arr[count] = temp;
            count++;
        }
        if (c == 1)
        {
            printf ("Too many values\n");
            return count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The output is not what I want. This is what I get when I run it.

```
Enter numbers with spaces between them
5 4 3 2 1
Too many values
The array is:
4 
The sorted array is:
4
```

I need the program to properly take in all the elements and not have the 'Too many values' thrown if the user only inputs 5 elements.

It should only print the 'Too many values' when the array is over 10 (`MAXSIZE`) elements. As of right now it only takes the first or second element of the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code

Comment: break your problem down. you should write a bunch of programs which do only one thing each. this will help you get a foundation which you can use for combining tasks alter.

Comment: Ok, your code appears to have all of the pieces that you described. So what's the question?

Comment: @user3386109 The question has been updated

Comment: The `while` loop should be `while( (c=scanf("%i", &temp)) != EOF)` and the `count<max` should be before `arr[count]=temp` inside the `else`.

Comment: Like so? else{
            count<max;
            arr[count]=temp;
            count++;
        }

Comment: The code should check whether `count` is less than `max` before putting the value into the array.

Comment: I still get the same issues

Comment: @CECE What does your program look like now?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I explained up above in my original post what it looks like. When i enter in numbers it returns 'Too many values' and then lists the first or second number in the array. I only want it to say 'Too many values' if there are over 10 elements, and then I want it to sort the first 10 elements anyway.

Comment: You wrote "I still get the same issues", so I thought you had made some changes and tried them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an assignment you want to do yourself, but the problem you’re asking about is in your `getArray()` function.  It’s checking the wrong value, unrelated to the number of elements read in, when it prints the error message about too many elements.  You also tell it to keep trying to read while *either* you haven’t encountered `EOF` *or* you haven’t read in the maximum number of elements, and you should look up what `scanf()` actually returns; you probably meant to check `feof(stdin)`.  Among other bugs, the function also throws away the first value it reads by overwriting it.

What you seem to want to do: is keep a count of the number of elements read, read in an element while this count is less than the maximum and there is valid input remaining; store the input in the array; increment the count.  Your check for too much input should be that the count is at maximum and `feof(stdin)` is false, and it should be after the while loop, not inside the body.