# Why does the C program stop executing after providing 1 element?

Tags: c

I am writing a program to check whether a set is a proper subset of a set or not. I am dynamically allocating memory for both of the sets(arrays) but after I provide one element the program stops executing.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
  int setID(int arr[],int arr2[],int size,int size2)
{
    int counter =0;
    for (int i=0; i<size2;i++)
    {
            if (arr2[i] == arr[i])
            {
                counter++;
            }


    }
    if (counter == (size2))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;

}
int main ()
{
    printf("We are going to check if set A is a proper subset of B or not\n");
    printf("Please provide the cardinal number of set A \n");
    int a=0,b=0;

    scanf("%d",&a);
    int *p;
    p =(int*) malloc(a*sizeof(int));
    printf("Please provide the elements of Set A\n");
    for (int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",p[i]);
    }
    printf("Please provide cardinal number for set B\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int *p1;
    p1= (int*) malloc(b*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&p1[i]);
    }

    printf("Please note that 0 is false and 1 is true\n");
    printf("%d\n",setID(p,p1,a,b));
    return 0;

}
```

**Also have I passed the arguments correctly in the function: printf("%d\n",setID(p,p1,a,b)); **

Comment: How is C++ related to the question?

Comment: How do you know it stopped executing? Your shell prompt came back? You saw an error message? A debugger or other monitor told you it stopped with a certain exit code or signal?

Comment: The C++ bigots were complaining.  This *is* C-like, but that's really beside the point.  One problem I see off the bat: `scanf("%d",p[i]);`: this should probably be `scanf("%d",&p[i]);`.

Comment: Don't forget to consume those `\n` from the input.

Comment: `if (arr2[i] == arr[i])` was valid for all `int size,int size2`, you would only need to pass one size. Where is the guarantee that `size == size2`?

Comment: What are the input values ? if `a < b`  you have illegal access, see my answer

Comment: I cannot help but note that this question, in which a program does not execute code that is wanted, complements [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469299/why-my-code-repeat-itself-when-the-get-answer), in which a program does execute code that is not wanted. Therefore, on average, your two programs are correct. So clearly you should merge them and divide by two.

Answer (score 1):

There is one error here

```
scanf("%d",p[i]);
```

which should be

```
scanf("%d", &p[i]);
```

and which is correct a few lines further down when you did this with `p1`. You say the program stops after providing one element and this is consistent with the error.

There may be other errors too as posted by others.

Comment: eagle eyes, I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

in *setID* :

```
for (int i=0; i<size2;i++)
{
        if (arr2[i] == arr[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
        ...
```

you suppose the size of *arr* is >= the size of *arr2*, but this is not mandatory because you read their size rather than to use the same when you allocate the arrays and read their values

if `size < size2` (`a < b` in *main*) you go out of *arr* (*p* in *main*), the behavior is undefined