# Why does scanf enter a loop when I input a character?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I have to finnish a college project, and a part of my code is acting strangely.

The goal of that part is to get an user input of an integer and store it in a variable so that i can use it later, however if the user inputs a character I have to ask for the number again.

I used the `scanf` function to get the user input and put it inside a `while` loop to continuously ask for the input in case it's invalid.

The problem is that when a user inputs a character, the code freaks out and starts running the `while` loop without stopping in the `scanf` to get the user input.
It makes sense that the loop condition is always true but the strange part is that it doesn't stop to read new inputs.

I deconstructed my code in order to replicate the problem to make it easier to debug.
I know that there are some useless variables but in my original code they are useful, I just kept them there to make it look similar to the original.
I can only use `scanf` to get user input, despite knowing them, in this project I am only allowed to use scanf. I can't use `scanf`'s format to get characters, only numerical types are allowed in this project.

C11 is the version of the standart we are using in classes.

I'm sory if the solution for this is a dumb thing, I'm not good at C and I'm having some difficultlies this semester...

Thanks in advance.

```
    while (!verification) {
        printf(">>>"); //write values in here
        check = scanf("\n%d", &var); //input a number and store the number of valid inputs
        if (check) verification = 1; //if the input is a number then the while condition should turn to false with this statement
        printf("var = %d, check = %d, verification = %d\n", var, check, verification); //printing all variables
    }
```

Comment: I suggest changing `scanf("\n%d", &var)` to `scanf("%d", &var)`. The format specifier `%d` will remove any leading whitespace automatically.

Comment: *"If the user inputs a character I have to ask for the number again."* That character stays in the input buffer until you take steps to remove it. If a character cannot be processed in some context then `scanf` does not throw it away. Please consider using `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` or `strtol()`. Otherwise there are [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code) around on how to clear the input - it is a very frequent question.

Comment: You *"can only use `scanf` to get user input, despite knowing them, in this project I am only allowed to use `scanf`. I can't use `scanf`'s format to get characters, only numerical types are allowed in this project."* I don't see then how it is **possible** to remove the unwanted non-numeric characters which are blocking the input, when `scanf("%d", ...)` is the only way to input that is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user does not input an integer there are characters left in the input stream after the call to *scanf*. Therefor you need to read to end of line before making the next attempt to read an integer. Otherwise *scanf* will try to read the same non-integer characters again and again. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch, i, n;

    n = scanf("%d", &i);
    while (n == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong input, integer expected\n");
        do {
            ch = getchar();
        } while ((ch != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));
        n = scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    } else { /*n == EOF*/
        fprintf(stderr, "reading input failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very much, I spoke to my teacher about the getchar function and he replied that I can use it if I specify the line of thinking. It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @RicardoQuintela I'm glad to help. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `scanf()` to read input from the user.

It's really only meant for reading data that's known to be in a particular format, and input from a user... often isn't.

While you do correctly check the return value of `scanf("%d")`, and could fix the case where the input isn't a number, you'll still have problems if the input is either an empty line, or a number followed by something else (`123 foobar`).

In the case of an empty line `scanf()` will *continue waiting for non-whitespace characters*. This is probably confusing, since users will expect hitting enter to do *something*.

In the case there's trailing stuff after the number, that stuff stays in the input buffer, and the *next time* you read something, it gets read. This is again probably confusing, since users seldom expect their input to one question to also act as input to another.

Instead, read a full line with `fgets()` or `getline()`, then run `sscanf()` or `strtol()` on that. This is much more intuitive, and avoids the disconnect caused by `scanf()` consuming input lines only partially (or consuming more than one line). See also e.g. [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/6372809)

Here, using `getline()` (POSIX, even if not in standard C. Use `fgets()` instead  if `getline()` is not available):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    int result;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    while (1) {
       if (getline(&line, &len, stdin) == -1) {
           /* eof or error, do whatever is sensible in your case */
           return 1;
       }
       if (sscanf(line, "%d", &result) != 1) {
           printf("That didn't seem like number, please try again: ");
           continue; 
       } 
       break;
    }
    printf("You entered the number %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie, no, there was no reason for the semicolon

Comment: Note: `getline()` is not in the standard C library.

Comment: It is a college exercise and OP stated *"I can only use `scanf` to get user input, despite knowing them, in this project I am only allowed to use `scanf`. I can't use `scanf`'s format to get characters, only numerical types are allowed in this project."*

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, it's a very good opportunity for them to realize that not everything they're taught and demanded in college is sensible; and practice going back to their teacher with an argument as to why some other way would be better.

Comment: @WeatherVane, note that, taking that limitation strictly, the usual "loop over `getchar()` until you see the newline" solution is also out, though could be replaced with a `scanf()` reading single characters, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, I just commented below the question that I don't see how it is even possible.

Comment: @WeatherVane, ah, yes. And, despite you just quoting it, the "can't use scanf to get characters" part somehow eluded me. Oops. That does make it seem rather impossible indeed.

Comment: @ilkkachu: discarding the rest of the line is easy: `scanf("*[^\n]");`

Comment: @chqrlie, reading the rest of a line to discard it doesn't help with `scanf("%d")` continuing to read another line if the user just hits enter before giving any digits.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you must discard offending input when the conversion fails.

Here is a simple solution using only `scanf()` as instructed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter an number: ");
        switch (scanf("%d", &n)) {
        case 1:
            /* successful conversion */
            printf("The number is %d\n", n);
            return 0;
        case 0:
            /* conversion failure: discard the rest of the line */
            scanf("*[^\n]");  // discard characters before the newline if any
            scanf("*1[\n]");  // optional: discard the newline if present
            printf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
            continue;
        case EOF:
            /* input failure */
            printf("Premature end of file\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```