# Why program run for infinite times for character?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;

  do {
    printf("Enter a Number :");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%d \n", n);

    if (n % 7 == 0) {
      break;
    }
  } while (1);

  printf("Program Ends");

  return 0;
}
```

Why the problem run for infinite time for input of any character?

I want to know why it is happening? It should break from the loop because character is not divisible by 7?

Comment: Check return value of `scanf`. Read from docs (like, just google "C scanf") what the return value means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is scanf() causing infinite loop in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't read a character. This call: `scanf("%d", &n);` doesn't do anything because there is no number to read. It returns 0 to let you know it didn't read a number, but you don't check.