# Loop skips a scanf statement after the first time

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scanf

Here is the code for main():

```
int main (void)
{
float acres[20];
float bushels[20];
float cost = 0;
float pricePerBushel = 0;
float totalAcres = 0;
char choice;
int counter = 0;

for(counter = 0; counter < 20; counter++)
{   
    printf("would you like to enter another farm? "); 

    scanf("%c", &choice);

    if (choice == 'n')
    {
        printf("in break ");
        break;
    }

    printf("enter the number of acres: ");
    scanf("%f", &acres[counter]);

    printf("enter the number of bushels: ");
    scanf("%f", &bushels[counter]);

}


return 0;
}
```

Every time the program runs through the first scanf works fine but on the second pass through the loop the scanf to enter a character does not run.

Comment: Check out the answer in this post, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c

Comment: @MichaelOliver: Jonathan Leffler's solution seems better there than the accepted one. :)

Answer (score 5):

Add a space before `%c` in `scanf`. This will allow `scanf` to skip any number of white spaces before reading `choice`.

`scanf(" %c", &choice);` is the only change required.

Adding an `fflush(stdin);` before `scanf("%c", &choice);` will also work. `fflush` call will flush the contents of input buffer, before reading the next input via scanf.

In case of `scanf(" %c", &choice);` even if there is only a single character in the input read buffer, `scanf` will interpret this character as a valid user input and proceed with execution. Incorrect usage of scanf may result in a series of strange bugs [like infinite loops when used inside `while` loop].