# Why does scanf function get automatically previous '\n' value and how can I escape from this event?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm not new at writing code. But I'm just learning C language. I cannot understand this subject. Perhaps it is not an issue but now it is an issue for me. Would you please explain that?

Here is code, where I encounter with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char letter;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a letter:\n");
        scanf("%c", &letter);

        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            case 'i':
            case 'I':
            case 'u':
            case 'U':
            case 'o':
            case 'O':
                printf("%c is a vowel letter.\n", letter);
                break;
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                printf("%c is sometimes a vowel letter.\n", letter);
                break;
            default:
                printf("%c is not a vowel letter.\n", letter);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a letter:
a
a is a vowel letter.
Enter a letter:

 is not a vowel letter.
Enter a letter:
```

Comment: Try `scanf(" %c", &letter);` Note the space before the `%`

Comment: There a multiple ways of doing this: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work), or [maybe here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the format from `"%c"` to `" %c"` to make [`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) discard all whitespace (as determined by [`isspace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html), `" \v\f\r\n\t"` in the POSIX and C locales) before assigning the next character, whatever it may be.

Maybe a better alternative, read a whole line with [`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) and then use `sscanf` to parse it instead.

As an aside, take care that `scanf` can always fail. On success, it returns the number of assigned arguments.
Also, I strongly suggest you read the `scanf`-manpage I linked above (or even better, the C standard on `scanf`), because there are quite a lot of pitfalls you may not know yet.

Comment: You can also do `scanf("%s\n")` to consume the trailing newline.

Comment: @FUZxxl: That has a big disadvantage though: It waits until a non-whitespace it should not discard is entered.

Comment: It does exactly the right thing for input from terminal which is usually line-buffered. You press the key you want and then hit enter.

Comment: You know `\n` matches any amount of whitespace, not only that single enter?

Comment: I know. Which is the right thing, too, in most cases.