# Is it possible to have an nested conditional statement?

Tags: c, do-while

Im trying do-while condition and there's another while inside of it, im having a problem in "do you want to continue?", its skipping  it.. Is there anything wrong to my codes?

```
do {
    printf("\nEnter the start value:");
    scanf("%d", &start_value);
    printf("\nEnter the end value:");
    scanf("%d", &end value);
    printf("\nEnter the interval value:");
    scanf("%d", &interval_value);
    while (start_value <= end_value) {
        printf("%d ", start_value);
        start_value = start_value + interval_value;
    }
    printf("\nDo you want to continue?");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
} while (answer != 'N' || answer != 'n');
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &answer);` --> `scanf(" %c", &answer);`

Comment: Huh?  you are assigning values to the variables, "first" and "second", then never using them again.

Comment: OK, the answer from Weather Vane also adds a very valid point, but the "skipping" part is in the dupe. Please let me know if anyone disagrees withe the CV.

Comment: `start_value` and `end_value` should be `first` and `second` or vice versa.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: this duplicate is of very poor quality.  I'm sure there are better ones.

Comment: @Holow: you should accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Comment: @SouravGhosh can you explain what is the difference from this scanf("%c", &answer); to this scanf(" %c", &answer);?

Answer (score 3):

Your conditional statement

```
while(answer != 'N' || answer != 'n');
```

is always `true`. I suggest

```
while(answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');
```

(in addition to the first comment above from @SouravGhosh, which cleans off the `newline` left in the input buffer)

Comment: I would suggest also `if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1) break;`

Comment: My main problem is that, my "do you want to continue?" has been skipped, any suggestion what is my error?

Comment: @Holow the solution is in the first comment right at the top, which I mentioned in my answer. If that is unclear, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043617/something-is-wrong-with-the-scanfs-and-or-ifs-in-my-program-coffee-shop/39043835#39043835) suggests it too. Also, please have a good read of the man page for the `scanf` function.