# How can I fix my code? I think the issue is the first scanf?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to create a program that computes a value Vt given values for Vo, a, and tm. When I run the code, the program asks the first question then after I give it a value, it speeds through the code without letting me give values for the other two variables. I am programming in C. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () {

    float Vt;
    float Vo;
    float a;
    float tm;

    printf(" At what time in flight do you wish to know the velocity? To the 
    nearest hundredth. :");
    scanf(" %.2f", &tm);

    printf (" What is the angle of trajectory? :");
    scanf (" %.2f", &a);

    printf (" What is the initial velocity? :");
    scanf (" %.2f", &Vo);

    float sina = sin (a);
    float cosa = cos (a);
    float tana = tan (a);

    Vt = sqrt((pow((Vo * cosa), 2.0)) + (pow((Vo * sina - (9.8 *tm)), 2.0)));

    printf("\n\n\n\n %.3f", Vt);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c

Comment: Your main is really old, you should upgrade!

Comment: Try `%f` instead of `%.2f`

Comment: `scanf` doesn't work well for interactive UIs.  I'd just use `fgets` (or something similar) to put the data into a string and parse each line individually with `sscanf` (or just `atof`).

Comment: adding `\n` in end of printf may solve it

Answer (score 3):

Your scanf format strings are invalid. Change them to `"%f"`. That is, change

- `scanf(" %.2f", &tm);` to `scanf("%f", &tm);`
- `scanf(" %.2f", &a);` to `scanf("%f", &a);`
- `scanf(" %.2f", &Vo);` to `scanf("%f", &Vo);`

If you intended to scan **at most N characters** then you must use the `"%Nf"` format string (such as `"%2f"` or `"%3f"`), where N is an integer larger than 0.