# Why is getchar() required to not terminate my infinte loop?

Tags: c

In this program , `getchar` is apparently needed to continue the while(1) loop. If I remove `getchar()`, the program terminates after printing the sum of the two numbers.

```
  while (1) {
    printf("Input two integers\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    getchar();

    c = a + b;

    printf("(%d) + (%d) = (%d)\n", a, b, c);

    printf("Do you wish to add more numbers (y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
      continue;
    else
        break;
  }
```

Comment: Step through in a debugger to see why.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf` to make sure it read something, and print that result. It's hitting the break. This should help explain the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You have junk in the input buffer from the `scanf()` before the `getchar()`. In particular, the newline.

It's usually far easier to just up and rewrite everything to use `fgetc()`, but in this case you can make a lot of improvement by doing something like this:

```
do{
   scanf("%c", &ch);
   if (ch == '\n')
       printf("Do you wish to add more numbers (y/n)\n");
} while (ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y' && ch != 'n' && ch != 'N');

if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
  continue;
else
    break;
```